# What is the difference between "template <class T>" and "template <typename T>"?

Tags: c++, templates, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use 'class' or 'typename' for template parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213121/use-class-or-typename-for-template-parameters)

I see two different template class declarations:

```
template <class T> class SampleClass1
{
    // ...
};
```

and

```
template <typename T> class SampleClass2
{
    // ...
};
```

What is the difference between these two codes?

EDIT: I corrected the wrong keyword "typedef" to "typename".

Comment: the difference is that first one is correct, while second one is incorrect. Use `typename` instead of `typedef` in the second, then there will be no difference!

Comment: @Nawaz: Yeah, sorry for the wrong keyword.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If by

```
template <typedef T> class SampleClass2
```

you mean

```
template <typename T> class SampleClass2
```

then there is no difference.  The use of `class` and `typename` (in the context of a template parameter that refers to a type) is interchangeable.

The reason that both keywords are allowed here is historical. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/08/11/212768.aspx) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: The link is not working

Answer (score 15):

In case of template template paramater

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class Wrapper>
class Foo {
    //...
  private:
    Wrapper<T> data;
};
```

You have to use *class* before classname.
This is wrong:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> typename Wrapper>
```

but this is ok:

```
template <typename T, template <class> class Wrapper>
```

In other cases they are interchangeable.

Comment: Update: there is a new proposal in the C++ standardization group that eliminate this difference. N4051: Allow typename in a template template parameter—Richard Smith