# gcc and class keyword

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I know that `typename` and `class` keywords are interchangeable in template arguments, but I thought only `typename` is allowed for nested classes specification.

Once I've accidentally wrote incorrectly "`class`" instead of "`typename`" for a nested class.
And I found is that gcc accepts `class` there too, so you can write something like:

```
class std::vector<T>::iterator it;
instead of
typename std::vector<T>::iterator it;
```

in your template.

Is this a gcc bug or does the standard really allow this syntax?

UPDATE: example of code:

```
template <typename T>
void test()
{
     class std::vector<T>::iterator it;
}
```

Comment: why don't you post the code? and which version of gcc?

Comment: it works for any usage of class instead of typename. I tried this on gcc 4.1.2 and 4.3.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "template <class T>" and "template <typename T>"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534313/what-is-the-difference-between-template-class-t-and-template-typename-t)

Comment: @rubenvb: Nah, this is about the `typename` before nested type(def)s.

Comment: @Xeo: is there a fundamental difference? I also found the typename<->class thing fishy, and never got a full and complete answer.

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, there is a difference. In template declarations, they are indeed interchangeable. Not for nested types though.

Comment: This question might be clearer if you used the correct terminology: "dependent name" (rather than "nested class").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class a::b` is an elaborated type specifier. Name lookup for an elaborated type specifier ignores non-type names. So if you are parsing a template, you can assume two things:

- When we are instantiating and do name-lookup for `b`, either name lookup gives us a type, or it errors out (wouldn't find any name).

In C++0x for that reason, `class a::b` doesn't need `typename` (you can't put it anywhere anyway on a elaborated type specifier). C++03 doesn't allow that, so GCC appears to implement the C++0x rules as an extension.

That's not particularly bad. Every real compiler implements rules that are sensible and easy to implement in their C++03 version, on their behalf, even if formally they would need to reject it. However, `class a::b` *must* lookup to a class name. If it's merely a typedef, then the lookup for the elaborated type specifier is invalid.

Note that `class a::b` is the only way to ignore non-type names in a lookup (except for arcane cases like before a `::` in a qualified name that have similar special rules). For example

```
template<typename T> 
struct A { typename T::type t; } 

struct B { class type { }; int type; };

// invalid, even though GCC accepts that incorrectly
A<B> a;
```

If you compile to C++0x, and you use `class T::type t;`, then the code becomes valid, because `class T::type` ignores the data member, but finds the nested class.

Comment: so this is a c++0x extension? ok, good to know that. However it is a bit strange that it is enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

Section 14.6 ("Name resolution") in ISO 14886:2003 seems to be the definition of how this is supposed to work.  Paragraph 3 says:

> A *qualified-id* that refers to a type and in which the *nested-name-specifier* depends on a *template-parameter* (14.6.2) shall be prefixed by the keyword `typename` to indicate that the *qualified-id* denotes a type, forming an *elaborated-type-specifier* (7.1.5.3).

No mention of the `class` keyword.  I think this is a GCC bug.

Comment: thanks, so this should be a bug like I suspected. I'll check it with the most recent gcc version and will report this bug if it is still there.

Answer (score 1):

It fails to compile with Comeau Online (Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008 11:28:09)), so at least one of the two compiler has a bug.

```
error: typedef "iterator" may not be used in an elaborated
          type specifier
       class std::vector<T>::iterator it;
```

Comment: Interesting, now I'd like to know what the standard says about this.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the Standard seems to confirm that typename should be used. From 14.6/2:

> A   name   used   in   a   template  declaration   or   definition   and  that is   dependent   on   a  template-parameter  is assumed not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified by the keyword typename.

Answer (score 0):

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/BeL37) shows a nice error message when the dependent name doesn't resolve to a class. So your example only works because `iterator` is indeed a `class`. :)

---

**Edit**: MSVC fails to compile even if the dependent is indeed a class,

> [error C2242](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te5w3zxd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): typedef name cannot follow class/struct/union

**Edit 2**:
This seems to be a MSVC bug, as g++ and Comeau online compile just fine if the dependent name is a class.

Answer (score -1):

I'm still loss at what happen.  I'd put a comment if putting code there wasn't problematic.

```
template <typename Foo>
void f()
{
    class Foo::bb x;
}

struct X {
    typedef int bb;
};

int main()
{
    f<X>();
    return 0;
}
```

doesn't compile with gcc with an error during the instantiation.  It will compile if X::bb is a class.  Como has the same behavior.

Edit, I think I've a better understanding now.

```
class Foo::Bar;
```

is an elaborated-class-specifier. Foo::Bar is looked up as a qualified name (3.4.4/3).  As it is dependent, the look-up has to be done in the second phase, during instantiation.  Then if it isn't found or if it isn't a class-name or enum-name, the elaborated-class-specifier is ill-formed.

TL;DR g++ doesn't seem to have a bug.