# Passing a std container to a templated class

Tags: c++, templates

Why doesn't this work?

```
template <typename T, typename U>  
class TSContainer {  
private:  
   U<T> container;  
};
```

called as:

```
TSContainer<int, std::vector> ts;
```

I think a solution might be:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> typename C>  
class TSContainer  
{  
        C<T> container;  
};
```

but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Right, that's it. I am going to begin ordering the violent execution of _any_ Stack Overflow user who complains that something "doesn't work".

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: You do amazing things on this site, but seriously, go get ice cream and a book.  Someone else will police for a while. :D

Comment: @Mooing: I'm stuck at home tonight. :( I am going to take you up on that, though, since I'm fresh out of vote allowance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
#include <vector>
template <typename T, template<typename, typename> class C>  
class TSContainer  
{  
    C<T, std::allocator<T> > container;  
};

int main() {
  TSContainer<int, std::vector> a;
}
```

Note that `std::vector` takes two template parameters with the second being defaulted to `std::allocator`. Alternatively, you can write:

```
#include <vector>
template <typename T, template<typename, typename = std::allocator<T> > class C>  
class TSContainer  
{  
        C<T> container;  
};

int main() {
  TSContainer<int, std::vector> a;
}
```

Both of these force the selection of the allocator on you. If you want to control which allocator is used by your vector (i.e. what is used as second template parameter to `C`), you can also use this:

```
#include <vector>
template <typename T, template<typename, typename> class C, typename A = std::allocator<T> >  
class TSContainer  
{  
        C<T, A> container;  
};

int main() {
  TSContainer<int, std::vector> a;
}
```

This is the most flexible solution.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Is there any specific reason you used class instead of typename there? I'm new to templates (as you've no doubt guessed), and not aware of the conventions.

Comment: @JonathanWinks: `typename` and `class` are interchangeable in this context; some prefer `class`.

Comment: @JonathanWinks There's discussion and an answer about `typename` vs `class` here: [C++: Use 'class' or 'typename' for template parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213121/c-use-class-or-typename-for-template-parameters)

Comment: Actually, it must be `class`. Normally, wherever you write `typename` you can also write `class`, but if the keyword is preceded by `template`, it should read `class`.

Comment: @Adam: That's the kind of information I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Default template-template parameter is required in the second version AFAIK: How would compiler know what `C<T>` means if we did not specify the default for the second template-template parameter?

Comment: @AdamZalcman: Well I never! to geordi: `{ Foo<int, std::vector> foo; } template <typename T, template <typename, typename = std::allocator<T> > typename C> struct Foo { C<T> container; };`, and back: `error: expected 'class' before 'C'`. Switching solves. `14.1/2` in n3290 (just about). Learnt something here today. Seems like a silly thing, though.

Comment: @Adam : My mistake, and I like your 3rd take best. :-]

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be much more easy to simply do something like:

```
#include <vector>
template <typename C>  
class TSContainer  
{  
    C container;  
};

int main() {
  TSContainer<std::vector<int> > a;
}
```