# template paramters: example from Modern C++ Design

Tags: c++, c++-loki

I have read "Modern C++ Design" 
and I have a question in its sample code

in p278 p279 
or refer to Loki's source if you don't have the book 
**BasicDipatcher::Add** and **BasicDispatcher::Go** in MutilMethods.h

in page p278 bottom to p279 up 
it has a piece of sample code

```cpp
typedef BasicDispatcher<Shape> Dispatcher;
void HatchRectanglePoly(Shape& lhs, Shape& rhs) {...}
Dispatcher disp;
disp.Add<Rectangle, Poly>(HatchRectanglePoly);
```

I found in function Go, its arguments are BaseLhs&, BaseRhs& 
which in this case, should be **Shape&, Shape&**

and in function Add, its arguments are SomeLhs&, SomeLhs&, 
which in this case, should be **Rectangle&, Poly&**

so the key won't match anyway because they are different

therefore the callback(HatchRectanglePoly) won't be called 
(If I add disp.Go.... in the samele code), 
 
and instead, 
a std:runtime_error will be thrown

Am i correct??

thanks

Comment: hope you can paste more code here, such as the declaration of Add and Go

Comment: source can be found in [loki doc](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00658.html)

Answer (score 0):

The BaseLhs and BaseRhs are template parameters. Just like function parameter, the actual value will be provided when you *use* it (instantiate the template), not when you define it.

```
template
<
  class BaseLhs,
  class BaseRhs = BaseLhs,
  typename ResultType = void,
  typename CallbackType = ResultType (*)(BaseLhs&, BaseRhs&)
>
class BasicDispatcher
```

By default, BaseRhs is the same as BaseLhs.

```
typedef BasicDispatcher<Shape> Dispatcher;
Dispatcher disp;
```

Here, we instantiate a version of BasicDispatcher, the BaseLhs is Shape, the BaseRhs is Shape too (since we provide only 1 template argument). In this instantiation, the `Go` method is somewhat like this:

```
void Go(Shape& lhs, Shape& rhs);
```

The same goes for `Add`.

In short: The type name written in template<...> is just a placeholder, it will be substituted by actual type when use.

Hope you find this helpful.

P.S: About the `class` and `typename` inside the angle bracket, they have the same meaning, I guess it's just a [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/213146/4862058) to the reader that BaseLhs and BaseRhs will always be classes.