# Declaring a struct in a template class, undefined for member functions

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I'm currently trying to implement a sort algorithm in a list template class using node structures private to the list class. I'm using a few private recursive functions which return a pointer to a node type which causes g++ to give me a declaration error. Here's a sample of what I have -

```
template<class T>
class SList
{
private:
    struct NODE
    {
        T* elem;
        NODE* next;
    } *_head, *_tail;

NODE* sort(NODE* node);

public:
    //other declarations...

}

template<class T>
NODE* SList<T>::sort(NODE* node) //Error: 'NODE' does not name a type
{
    //sorting algorithm
}
```

Is this a limitation of c++ or am I missing something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since `Node` is an internal class you need to tell the compiler where `Node`'s definition comes from.

Furthermore, Node's definition changes depending on what `SList`'s template parameter is (it is a *dependent type*)

So you have to explicitly refer to `Node` as such:

```
template<class T>
typename SList<T>::NODE* SList<T>::sort(typename SList<T>::NODE* node) 
{
    //sorting algorithm
}
```

- Note the `typename` because Node is a dependent type (it depends on the type of `SList`)
- Note the `SList<T>::Node` because Node is a type **dependent** on `SList`'s type.

Comment: Can it be achieved by "decltype" now?

Comment: @dahohu527 I'm not sure I understand the question. Can what be achieved? That said, no, I don't think decltype helps in this instance - but if you could clarify I may be able to better answer your question

Answer (score 4):

Below works fine:

```
template<class T>
typename SList<T>::NODE* SList<T>::sort(typename SList<T>::NODE* node)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> Is this a limitation of c++

**No**. Because there can be any structure/type named `NODE` outside the scope of `SList<>`; so actually it's a **facility** which C++ provides you where you can have same name types in different scope.

"Why I need keyword `typename`" can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213121/use-class-or-typename-for-template-parameters).

Answer (score 2):

The type you want to refer to is within SList, thus you must refer to it as such:

```
template<class T>
typename SList<T>::NODE* SList<T>::sort(typename SList<T>::NODE* node);
```

Comment: You need to add `typename` because `Node` is a dependent type

Comment: Ah Thanks! I also got a error which I fixed by adding typename after the template declaration.

EDIT: Beat me to it