# "error: no matching function for call to"

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I was on codepad and I was trying to build up my skills using C++. I'd never used templates much before, so I tried looking into how to use them. The code below is the result, and unfortunately, it does not work. I did try to search for solutions to my problem, but since I don't have much experience using templates, I couldn't make any connections between my problem and other problems. So, I decided to ask for help.

```
template <class A>
class Vector2 {
public:
    A x,y;
    Vector2(A xp, A yp){
        this->x = xp;
        this->y = yp;
    }
};

template <class B, class A>
class rayToCast {
public:
    rayToCast(B angle, Vector2<A> origin, Vector2<A> point1, Vector2<A> point2){
        this->RAngle = angle;
        this->Point1 = point1;
        this->Point2 = point2;
    }
private:
    B RAngle;
    Vector2<A> point1,point2;
};

int main(){
    rayToCast<short int, float> ray(45, Vector2<float>(0.0, 0.0), Vector2<float>(-10.0, -3.0), Vector2<float>(5.0, 7.0));
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
t.cpp: In constructor 'rayToCast<B, A>::rayToCast(B, Vector2<A>, Vector2<A>, Vector2<A>) [with B = short int, A = float]':
t.cpp:26:   instantiated from here
Line 14: error: no matching function for call to 'Vector2<float>::Vector2()'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @H2CO3 Can you back that statement up? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213121/use-class-or-typename-for-template-parameters

Comment: @H2CO3 It makes no difference.

Comment: Learn to use member initializer lists: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rayToCast` constructor tries to initialize `point1` and `point2` by calling `Vector2`'s default constructor. But it doesn't have one.

You either have to provide a default constructor for the vector class, or explicitly initialize the members of `rayToCast`. One way is to do like this:

```
rayToCast(B angle, Vector2<A> origin, Vector2<A> point1, Vector2<A> point2)
   : RAngle(angle), point1(point1), point2(point2)
{ }
```

Comment: Ah, every day I learn that I've learned almost nothing about C++. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The error is not about the templates.

Your `Vector2` class has no default constructor, but you want to create it with a default constructor in the constructor of `rayToCast`.

Use a member initializer list in the constructor of `rayToCast` or create a default constructor in `Vector2`.

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues in your code:

Vector2 has no default constructor, default constructor will be called when pass Vector2 to `rayToCast` constructor.

```
rayToCast(B angle, Vector2<A> origin, Vector2<A> point1, Vector2<A> point2)
```

You need to add default constructor to Vector2 and initialize `x,y` to default value:

```
template <class A>
class Vector2 {
public:
    A x,y;
    Vector2() : x(), y() {}  // default constructor
    Vector2(A xp, A yp){
        this->x = xp;
        this->y = yp;
    }
};
```

Also, you have typo, should be Point1, Point2 instead of point1/point2.

```
class rayToCast {
public:
    rayToCast(B angle, Vector2<A> origin, Vector2<A> point1, Vector2<A> point2){
        this->RAngle = angle;
        this->Point1 = point1;
        this->Point2 = point2;
    }
private:
    B RAngle;
    Vector2<A> Point1;    // capital P
    Vector2<A> Point2;    // capital P
};
```

Comment: The issue is the lacking default constructor.  The capitalization is completely unrelated, and not necessarily a problem.

Comment: the main issue is default constructor but when I see it, why not point out?

Comment: So, it is :p  Missed where they are incorrectly used in the constructor.  Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't declare a constructor, you get the default constructors auto-generated for you (default constructor and copy constructor).

When you do declare a constructor, you no longer get the auto-generated constructors (so you have to manually define the others if you want them).

Because you defined `Vector2(A xp, A yp)`, the compiler no longer auto-generates `Vector2()` for you, and you have to define `Vector2()` yourself if you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Take this part of your code:

```
rayToCast(B angle, Vector2<A> origin, Vector2<A> point1, Vector2<A> point2){
    this->RAngle = angle;
    this->Point1 = point1;
    this->Point2 = point2;
}
```

To the uninitiated C++ programmer it looks like this initialises `Point1` and `Point2`, but it does not. Initialisation is either done by default (which cannot happen here, since `Vector2<A>` has no default constructor), or in the *member initialisation list* (which you didn't use); your assignments in the constructor *body* are just that: after-the-fact assignments.

You probably have your reasons for not giving `Vector<A>` a default constructor, so fix `rayToCast` by having its constructor properly *initialise* those `Point1`/`Point2` members from the constructor arguments:

```
rayToCast(B angle, Vector2<A> origin, Vector2<A> point1, Vector2<A> point2)
   : RAngle(angle)
   , point1(point1)
   , point2(point2)
{}
```

I'd also recommend tidying up your variable and argument names, as they confused me a little *(caps here, not there, nowhere, everywhere, where, there!)*.

Answer (score 0):

As other's have already pointed out, the error is that you lack a default constructor. Use the syntax that Bo Persson suggested.

Another error is that variable names are case-sensitive, e.g., in the constructor of `rayToCast` you write:

```
this->Point1 = point1;
```

However, you named the class attribute `point1`. Note that it is not the same as:

```
this->point1 = point1;
```