# How to distinguish data structure template and function template in C++?

Tags: c++, class, templates, data-structures, function-templates

I have learned that data structures can be created using templates in the following way:

```
template<typename T>
struct X {
   T weight;
   int age;
};
```

The functions can also use templates in the following way:

```
template <class T>
T func_name(int age, T human) {
    something_here;
}
```

One of the difference s is that in the first case we use `typename` while in the second case we use `class`.

I found code that contains the following:

```
template<typename S, typename T>
bool is_null(const row<T>& r)
```

So, what I cannot understand is why we use `typename` (and not `class`) in combination with functions. Shouldn't we use `class`?

Comment: You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213121/use-class-or-typename-for-template-parameters) relevant to yours. Or perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/c-difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates)

Answer (score 3):

In this context, there is no technical difference between the keyword `typename` and the keyword `class`.  It's just a matter of style.  The meaning of your first two code examples would not change one bit if they started with `template<class T> struct X` and `template <typename T> T func_name(int age, T human)`.  (I tend to use `class` when I mean to imply the template parameter should be a class, and not something like `int`.)

Comment: Are `typename` and `class` always interchangeable or only in this context?

Comment: Only when declaring a template parameter.

Comment: @Roman, you can't declare a class using the `typename` keyword (an obvious difference); you can't also [disambiguate dependent types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/613132#613132) using the `class` keyword. But when declaring type parameters of a template, `class` and `typename` are interchangeable.

Comment: @Roman When it comes to declaring template parameters the two keywords are always interchangeable, except for [template template parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11311432/241631) when you must use `class`

Answer (score 0):

When `template` was first introduced, it ONLY allowed the existing keyword `class` as an indicator "this is a template argument". Since this becomes rather daft when the template argument isn't actually a class (a function pointer, integer type, or some other "not a class" type), the `typename` was introduced to make it more clear that `template<typename T> struct something { T x; };` allows `something<int> a;` as well as `something<name_of_class> a;`.

For all intents and purposes, `class` and `typename` in the case of template parameters is interchangeable, and it's just a matter of style which you choose to do [most people probably prefer if you stick to one, not mixing the two - or, perhaps use `class` when the type HAS TO be a class, and `typename` when it can be "any" type].

Answer (score 0):

In the context of template parameter definitions the keywords `typename` and `class` are synonymous.

Just about everyone has a convention they tend to stick with.  I personally prefer to always use `class` here and reserve the `typename` keyword for its other use.

The other use for `typename` is to disambiguate a dependent type in a template definition or declaration.

Here is an example from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typename):

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& t)
{
   // declares a pointer to an object of type T::bar
   T::bar * p;
}

struct StructWithBarAsType {
   typedef int bar;
};

int main() {
   StructWithBarAsType x;
   foo(x);
}
```

If you look closely you will notice in the line `T::bar * p;`, `bar` is dependent on a template parameter `T` which is ambiguous to the compiler as `bar` can be either a type or a value depending on the context of the type `T` used for instantiating the template.  The default is to treat `bar` as a value so the meaning would be to multiply `T::bar` by `p` which is not what we want.

The solution is to qualify the dependent type with the `typename` keyword.

```
typename T::bar * p;
```

This alerts the compiler to the fact that we intend to treat `bar` as a type.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one spot where they differ (when declaring template parameters), and that is when using template-templates.

The following is well-defined C++

```
template <template <typename> class TT> struct example_one {};
```

while this is not:

```
template <template <typename> typename TT> struct example_two {};
```

Since it seems like you're just starting out with C++/templates, this corner case won't concern you for a while :-) Aside from the above, class template, function template, it doesn't matter: typename and class are synonymous.