# Templated arguments

Tags: c++, templates

What is proper syntax for a function that takes a template parameter as an argument i.e.

```
 void myFunction (const Foo::Bar<T>& x)
```

Is it

```
 template<typename T>
 void myFunction (const typename Foo::Bar<T>& x)
```

Also, should I use

```
template<typename T>
```

Or

```
template<class T>
```

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213121/use-class-or-typename-for-template-parameters?rq=1 (note both of these are in the related links on the right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it.

```
template<typename T>
void myFunction (const typename Foo::Bar<T>& x)
```

Is correct. It doesn't matter whether you use `class` or `typename`. `typename` is preferred, `class` is in there for historical reasons. They are completely identical, though. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213121/2887128) for some explanation.