# Difference in template functions

Tags: c++, templates

What's the difference between `template<typename T>` and `template<class T>` ?

I always use the "typename" version, but I came across with this class one and I need to know the difference..

Comment: [And here's another Q&A with more opinions on `class` vs `typename`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213121/use-class-or-typename-for-template-parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. You can use either `typename` or `class` to designate a type parameter in a template.

Comment: Well there is but in the OP's example there isn't

Comment: @Kerrek I thought it may differ because `class` only for classes.. and therefore `typename` for a specific case..

Comment: @J.Seixas: You may have thought that, but in spite of that, there is no difference.

Comment: @NathanOliver what do you mean?

Comment: @J.Seixas From the answer in the linked to dupe if you have `template < template < typename, typename > class Container, typename Type >` `class Container` cannot be replaced with `typename Container`

Comment: @NathanOliver so there is no "big" difference . Appreciated

Comment: @KerrekSB ideone is broken or not showing warnings.  That is a C++17 feature: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea079e6d967d4389

Comment: @KerrekSB What standard are you looking at?  I don't have the actual C++14 standard but I have draft N3797 Which should be the C++14 standard and it is not in there.  Also according to [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/) it has yet to be adopted.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Your first comment doesn't seem to apply. The difference concerns template parameters, but my answer is explicitly constrained to type parameters.