# Is "enum class" a class type in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, c++17

I read about enumeration declaration in C++ using [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

Then I have made **Enum class** and check whether it is a class type or not using `std::is_class`.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Enum 
{
    red = 1, blue, green
};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_class<Enum>::value << '\n';
}
```

Then I compiled and ran in **G++** compiler on Linux platform, it prints `false` value.

So **Is `enum` class type or not?** If enum is a class type, then why I'm getting **false** value?

Comment: (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class has your example)

Comment: No, enum is not a class type, even when introduced with `enum class`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`enum class` is not a `class` definition - the combination of keywords is used to define a *scoped enumeration*, which is a completely separate entity from a `class`.

`std::is_class` correctly returns `false` here. If you use `std::is_enum`, it will return `true`.

---

[From the Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#2):

> The enumeration type declared with an enum-key of only `enum` is an unscoped enumeration, and its enumerators are unscoped enumerators. The enum-keys `enum class` and `enum struct` are semantically equivalent; an enumeration type declared with one of these is a scoped enumeration, and its enumerators are scoped enumerators.

There is no mention of an `enum class` being a *"`class` type"* anywhere in the Standard.

Comment: "There is no mention of an enum class being a class type anywhere." except for the keyword used to declare it in the code :/

Comment: @will: edited my answer, hopefully clarifying what I meant

Comment: it wasn't a jibe at your answer, but more at the syntax chosen for enums...

Comment: Is it syntax or semantics? (I don't mean that in the colloquial sense, as in 'pedantics'.) I'm looking at another question regarding `typename` and `class` being synonymous within the context of template parameters, e.g. `enum class EC {}; template<class C> TC { typedef std::is_class<C> type; };` (`TC<EC>` is well-formed, but its `type::value` is false.) It would seem that 'class' as a keyword (sometimes? only?) qualifies the type/context you're referring to. I'd love to hear it articulated better - the refs only bother describing individual cases.

Answer (score 22):

Despite the `class` keyword, enumerations are not classes. That keyword only means the enumerators must respect certain scoping rules (and also prevents implicit integral conversions).

The choice of the keyword is due to the aspects brought about by the new type<sup>1</sup>, and how scoped enumerators were hacked together in the pre-C++11 era, to obtain said aspects:

```
struct Enum { // could just as well be a class.
  enum {
    red = 1, blue, green
  };
};
```

Which only allowed the enumerators to be accessed via the qualified name. Though it didn't prevent implicit conversions like true scoped enumerations do.

`is_class` is meant to identify the class/struct aggregate types.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> [B. Stroustrup - C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum)</sub>

Comment: Stroustrup says this regarding choice of the keyword: _"The new enums are "enum class" because they combine aspects of traditional enumerations (names values) with aspects of classes (scoped members and absence of conversions)."_ (from [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum)).

Comment: @zett42 - Shamelessly added to the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect that one of the primary reasons it is called "enum class" rather than something more explicit (such as "scoped enum") is simply for keyword re-use. Adding new keywords to the language is a difficult process as it can break backwards compatibility, which is why "final", for example, is not a keyword but an identifier. "enum class" tenuously made sense and re-used existing keywords, so they went with that. Pure conjecture, of course :)

Comment: @AzCopey - I'd put money on your wager :) I suspect the fact it also happens to have similarities to an existing idiom is a happy coincidence.