# Howto extend std::list and create custom function?

Tags: c++, list, std, extends

Have a custom std::list class helper:

```
#ifndef __WLIST_H

    #define __WLIST_H

    #include <list>
    using namespace std;

    template <class T >
    class WList : public std::list<T>
    {
        public:
            void wAdd();
            void wRemove();
            bool wContains();
            void wGet();
            void wClear();
            int  wSize();

    };

#endif /*__WLIST_H*/
```

Howto declare the custom `add` new item?, in the class declare:

```
#include "WList.h"

template<class T>
void WList<T>::wAdd(/*???*/)
{
    this->push_back(/*???*/);
}
```

Howto set the object type in the argument?

Comment: Can't you just pass a class of type `T` to `wAdd` (`void WList<T>::wAdd(T object_to_add)`) and then add it like `this->push_back(object_to_add)`?

Comment: If you don't know the answer to *Howto declare the custom add new item?*, you need to understand the fundamentals of the language from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Also, don't derive from `std::list`. The standard prohibits it.

Comment: @apalomer does not work, the compiler says an error: `WList<Rectangle>::wAdd(Rectangle) is not defined`

Comment: @RSahu a good book in spanish?

Comment: Spanish? That's a link to [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @e-info128 you have to implement it in the header otherwise it won't be instantiated.

Comment: Never ever write `using namespace std;` in a header file.

Comment: `void wAdd();` add *what*?

Answer (score 0):

Although [**you should not inherit from stl containers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate) I will give you the answer with your same example.

When using a function or a class template you have to implement the code in the [header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file), otherwise, the compiler will not instantiate the right functions. When defining function templates the compiler creates a specific class of the function template for the given class. For example, when you do `WList<Rectangle>` the compiler creates an instance of the `WList` for the template `Rectangle`. To do so the compiler needs all the function/class templates in the code that is compiling, otherwise, some functions (the ones that are not in the header file) will be missing and a `func is not defined` or `undefined reference to func` error happens.

Your code should be something like:

**WList.h**

```
#include <list>

template <typename T >
class WList : public std::list<T>
{
public:
    void wAdd(T obj)
    {
        this->push_back(obj);
    }    
};
```

or

```
#include <list>

 template <typename T >
 class WList: public std::list<T>
 {
     public:
         void wAdd(T obj);

 };

 template<typename T>
 void WList<T>::wAdd(T obj)
 {
     this->push_back(obj);
 }
```

**Main**

```
int main() {

    WList<double> list;
    list.wAdd(2);
}
```

**A more proper way of doing this** would be without inheriting from the stl container:

```
#include <list>

template <typename T >
class WList
{
public:
    void wAdd(T obj)
    {
        m_data.push_back(obj);
    }    
protected:
    std::list<T> m_data;
};
```

**Moreover**, note that using `template<typename T>` is better than `template<class T>` to [avoid static ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213121/use-class-or-typename-for-template-parameters) between `class` as template and `class` as class definition

Comment: An even more proper way: `m_data.push_back(std::move(obj));`.

Comment: only if @e-info128 uses [c++11 though](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), isn't it?

Comment: and if declare function name in the header but declare functionality in the class? is `WList<T>::wAdd(T obj)`?

Comment: You can declare the function outside of the class definition, but if the function is not declared in the header file then it won't be instantiated when the class for a given type is instantiated. Look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

**In C++11, if it's available:**

Templates need to be defined in a header file, you can write inside a class:

```
void wAdd(T&& obj) { this->push_back(std::move(obj)); }   
void wAdd(const T& obj) { this->push_back(obj); }
```

You might also want to consider emplace semantics:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void wEmplace(Ts&&... args) { this->emplace_back(std::forward<Ts>(args)...); }
```

And do not use `using namespace std;` in a header file!