# Template class with iterator to a STL container

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a template class which has an iterator of a STL container as  a member. That is how far I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename Element, template <class> class StdLibContainer>
struct ClassHoldingAnIteratorToAStandardContainer
{
    ClassHoldingAnIteratorToAStandardContainer(){}
    typename StdLibContainer<Element*>::iterator std_lib_iterator;
};


int main()
{
    vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
    ClassHoldingAnIteratorToAStandardContainer<int,vector<int>> holding_iterator_to_vec;
    //DOES NOT WORK, compiler says: expected a class template, got ‘std::vector<int>’
    return 0;
}
```

1. Could you explain the syntax `template <typename> class StdLibContainer`?
   I found it somewhere on stackoverflow. BUt I don't understand it.
2. How can I create an instance of `ClassHoldingAnIteratorToAStandardContainer` ? All my attempts failed so far. The compiler always gives the error message: `expected a class template, got ‘std::vector’

In the above example i want to assign `holding_iterator_to_vec` `vec.begin()`.

Comment: That's a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter). It requires a template instead of a type as argument.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ That question has nothing to do with template template parameters. It's one of the cases for `typename` that isn't mentioned in the answers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Okeh sorry, I was to fast here. Sounded so at a 1st glance.

Comment: @newandlost What's the problem you actually want to solve doing this? It sounds somehow weird, and I have doubts if there are better designs to achieve what you're actually want to do. XY problem?

Comment: do you need to know the type of the container? Why not just have the type of the iterator as template parameter?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have a class, that has e.g. int A, int B, and a stl container like vector<int> C_to_Z as member variable. In the end I want to create a custom iterator, that goes A,B and  then uses the iterator of the vector to go C to Z.

Answer (score 1):

`template <typename> class` is the same as `template <class> class`. Originally, when templates were introduced, they allowed two equivalent forms:

```
template<class T> struct Foo {};
// or
template<typename T> struct Foo {};
```

Do not ask me why! However, the same was not true for template template parameters:

```
template <template <class> typename T> struct Foo {};
```

was the only allowed syntax. Apparently, people were unhappy about it, so the syntax was relaxed.

As for your second question, `std::vector` takes **at least** two template arguments, data type and allocator. This is why a single argument template doesn't cut it before C++17. After C++17, it would work.

To make it universal, use

```
template<template <class...> class Container> struct Foo{};
```

Comment: Since C++17 `template <typename> class` can actually match `std::vector` (because the second template parameter has a default value).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's something I am not aware of! Do you have a link (or a name of the feature I can search for)?

Comment: Here's a revelant [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#150). And [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) has an example demonstrating this change (Ctrl+F `CWG 150`).

Comment: only the `...` in `<class...>` are for a pack the others are just "`etc...`" right?

Comment: @user463035818 Yup.

Comment: well actually there was a hidden "can you please make it more clear" in my comment ;). I tried to make it less ambiguous. Hope i didnt put anything wrong, just roll back if you dont like it

Comment: @HolyBlackCat much appreciated!

Comment: was sure if the correct "old" syntax was `<template <class> typename T>` or `<template <class> class T>`. Imho this whole issue about class vs typename is a bit ridiculous, would be interesting to know what was the original rationale

Comment: @user463035818 that's why I put `...` - to make it cut both ways - but I realize it could be too confusing. I think, it's better this way. And yes, I'd be curious to know the rationale too. I'd ask a question, but I am afraid it would be downvoted to minus infinity.

Comment: I was going to write a question, but then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/213135/4117728) which has half of the answer. For the other half my guess is that template template parameters came after the comitee decided to use `typename` rather than `class` for clarity (and keep allowing `class` for backward compatibility for normal tempalte parameters) and saw no obvious reason to allow `class` also there

Comment: My compiler only accepts `template <template <class> class T> struct Foo {};` For `template <template <class> typename T> struct Foo {}`; it says "invalid use of template-name"

Comment: And what is the correct syntax for initializing `ClassHoldingAnIteratorToAStandardContainer` ? I got a little bit confused.

Comment: `ClassHoldingAnIteratorToAStandardContainer<int,vector<int,std::allocator<int>>> holding_iterator_to_vec;` dos not work...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to know the type of the container, I would strongly recommend to keep your `ClassHoldingAnIteratorToAStandardContainer` independent of the concrete container type. If you just need the iterator, this is simpler and sufficient:

```
template<typename iterator>
struct iterator_wrapper {
    iterator iter;    
};
```

Thats the minimum you need to have an iterator as member :).

I dont really know what you want to use the iterator for, so just for the sake of an example lets add methods that actually use the iterator....

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename iterator>
struct iterator_wrapper {
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::value_type;
    iterator iter;    
    bool operator!=(const iterator& other) { return iter != other;}
    iterator_wrapper& operator++(){ 
        ++iter;
        return *this;
    }
    const value_type& operator*() { return *iter; }
};

template <typename iterator>
iterator_wrapper<iterator> wrap_iterator(iterator it) { 
    return {it}; 
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
    auto it = wrap_iterator(vec.begin());    
    for (;it != vec.end();++it) std::cout << *it;
```

}

Also there is a problem in your code.

```
typename StdLibContainer<Element*>::iterator
```

is for containers of pointers while in main you have `int`s. If you want to infer the iterator type from the container type then you can do it for example like this:

```
template <typename container, 
          typename iterator = typename container::iterator>
iterator_wrapper<iterator> wrap_begin(container& c) { 
    return {c.begin()}; 
}
```

which makes creating an `iterator_wrapper` as simple as

```
auto x = wrap_begin(vec);
```

Note that this answer applies to C++11, in newer standards there are deduction guides that make such `make_x` methods more or less superfluous afaik.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. My usecase is the following: I hvae a Container that could in principle be e.g. a std::vector. But always when an element is insterted a want that this new element is registerd also somewhere else. So I created a custom ElementContainer, with a insert function that inserts a element into the vector and additionally executes the function. But I still want to be able to iterate over ElementContainer as I could do over std::vector. That is why the ElementContainer needs an iterator that basically wraps the iterator of vector.

Comment: How could I incorporate `Element *  operator->() const;` in your solution?

Comment: @newandlost I updated the example to include an `operator*()const` , `operator->()const` is similar