# What's the most interesting wrong view people have on the difference between structure and class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, structure

What's the most interesting wrong view people have on the difference between structure and class in C++?

Comment: Stack Overflow is designed to support *right* answers, not wrong ones.

Comment: That using the 'struct' keyword rather than 'class' can act as some kind of documentation to take the place of real documentation.

Comment: That the difference between them is worth discussing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who are interested in what the actual difference is, the default access specified for structs is public, and for classes it is private. There is no other difference.

See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c/999810#999810).

> Member of a class defined with the keyword class are private by default. Members of a class defined with the keywords struct or union  are public by default.
>
> In absence of an access-specifier  for a base class, public is assumed when the derived class is declared struct and private is assumed when the class is declared class.

I can imagine a lot of people thinking that there will be a performance difference but there is not.

Comment: what about the size of an empty class and an empty struct?

Answer (score 9):

Classes are from Mars, and structs are from Venus.

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy to assume that a `struct` cannot have methods. This is false; I will sometimes put a constructor on a struct, for example.