# Implementing something like std::vector.back()

Tags: c++, oop

I would like to implement something like this because my application is divided into scenes and this gets sort of messy:

```
glEngine.scene[glEngine.current.currentScene].layer[glEngine.scene[glEngine.current.currentScene].currentLayer].Shapes.push_back(CGlShape());
```

instead I'd want to be able to do something like this:

```
glEngine.Scene().layer[glEngine.Scene().currentLayer].Shapes.push_back(CGlShape());
```

How could I make a function like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have no idea what your classes are, but just make a function:

```
struct glEngine
{
    // ...

    scene_type& Scene()
    {
        return scene[current.currentScene];
    }
};
```

You can also do this for `Scene`, returning the current layer:

```
struct scene_type
{
    // ...

    layer_type& Layer()
    {
        return layer[current.currentScene];
    }
};
```

Giving:

```
glEngine.Scene().Layer().Shapes.push_back(CGlShape());
```

You might also consider splitting the line up merely for the sake of readability:

```
scene_type& scene = glEngine.Scene();
layer_type& layer = scene.Layer();

layer.Shapes.push_back(CGlShape());
```

Lastly, the naming convention seems a bit weird, maybe rename the `Scene` and `Layer` functions to `current_scene` and `current_layer`.

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I did not know that structs could have functions!!!!!! you just saved me sooo many hours! Thanks

Comment: @Jex: Yup, [structs and classes are exactly the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c/999810#999810), except classes default to private in everything while structs are public toe everything.

Comment: I know even programmin teachers of c++ that think that struct is the former C struct and they are different from classes :).

Answer (score 0):

Use [typedef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) to simplify cumbersome expressions! Typedef is for that.