# what is difference between structure and class

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

consider that i need to answer this question for interview..

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c

Comment: Pasting that subject into the search box should have given you the result commented on by @rubenvb.

Answer (score 2):

in structure, the member access specifier are default to public while on class is private.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard interview question.

The standard (and correct) answer is "A struct's members are public by default while a class' members are private by default."

For bonus points, the full answer is "A struct's members are public by default and inheritance is public by default whereas a class's members and inheritance are private by default."