# What is the syntax for initializing a struct in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, struct

Can I build a constructor to initialize a struct this way:

```
mystruct struct1(a,b);
```

the same way I initialize a class?

Or do I have to use this way:

```
mystruct struct1=mystruct(a,b);
```

?

Comment: The only difference between a class and a struct in C++ is that struct members are public by default, whereas class members are private by default. Other than that, the 2 concepts are interchangeable.

Comment: @PaulKeister: Members and bases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same syntax as you use for `class`. In C++, there is no difference between them except for the default access specifiers which is `public` for `struct` and `private` for `class`. See here for detailed explaination: [Difference between struct and class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

In C++ there is no difference between a structure and a class except that the data members by default are public in case of `struct` and private in case of `class`.

Furthermore there are two common modes of initialization of objects in C++

[1) Direct Initialization 
2) Copy Initialization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm)

Comment: and of course the default inheritance, but that is sort-of not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are valid. you can do it either ways.