# structures and classes

Tags: c++, oop, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

do structures support OOP as classes??

Comment: in c++ do structures support the object oriented principles??

Comment: If you're talking about C++ then mention this in the question and add a `C++` tag.

Comment: do you own any C++ books? if yes then why dont you try searching this in that ?

Comment: There are no structures in C++. The `struct` keyword can be used to declare or define classes, just like the `class` and `union` keywords.

Answer (score 6):

in C++, there is almost no difference between struct and class.
yes OOP is available with the keyword struct.

you can consider both class and struct the same except that:

- by **default visibility** in struct is
  public, while it's private for class
- by **default inheritance** in struct is
  public: while it's private for class.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ except that `struct` members are **public** by default and `class` members are **private** by default. What ever else holds for `class` holds for `struct` as well in C++.

Comment: you forgot about inheritance accessors.

Comment: @Ashot : Yes, but Stephane has mentioned it. I believe OP should understand anything by default is public in struct and private in class. That is what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: @Philipp. What do you mean by different ?

Comment: The same as the others said. I was too late, and since it's already been said a thousand times, I'll delete my comment. But mentioning the difference with respect to inheritance visibility is extremely important and often forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

in C++ and .NET you can have methods defined for a struct as well, in C++ a struct has all members public by default while a class has members private by default. A struct can implement an interface but cannot derive a base class.

structs are value types while classes are reference types.

In my opinion and point of view since a struct cannot derive another class, it does not fully support OOP, that's why we have classes. :)

Comment: Not a .NET question (admittedly, was only revealed later on, therfore no downvote). Extra credit for not preaching the irrelevant and wrong "structs go to stack" though.