# Nameless object in C++

Tags: c++, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an unnamed type in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131691/what-is-an-unnamed-type-in-c)

I am new in OOP with C++. I would really appreciate if anyone can simply give me some idea about the "nameless object." When it is created and what is the advantage? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by "nameless object"?

Comment: Refer this link http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=267811, it may help u.

Comment: new in OOP with C++, you are new to C++

Answer (score 4):

Probably you mean "anonymous" which is the same as it's a Greek word which translates to "without name". So try looking for anonymous classes and methods to learn more:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163970.aspx

For an easy example let's say :

```
rectangle(point(0,0),point(100,100));
```

The `point(0,0)` and `point(100,100)` create "nameless" objects (I hope you are referring to this and not something else).

Comment: well… if `rectangle` and `point` are both types, then that line will create three anonymous temporaries and then discard them.

Comment: As Potatoswatter says, these are anonymous *temporaries*, which are not the same as anonymous *types*, but it's not entirely clear from the question in which of these @Skeptic is interested.