# Creating new structs on the fly

Tags: c++

I am (very) new to C++, and am having some issues understanding structs. I'm using example code from a course, so I have:

```
struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
}
```

In another bit of code, I want to write the following:

```
drawLine(point1, new Point(x, y));
```

This does not work, and I understand that I am trying to declare a struct as if it were a class, but is there a way to do this? I have currently written a helper function which returns a Point from an x,y, but this seems roundabout.

Comment: You've got a memory leak unless `drawLine()` takes ownership of the object.

Comment: Just add a constructor (works with struct just like class) `Point(int px,int py) : x(px), y(py) {}`

Comment: C++ is fundamentally different from C# or Java -- you manage your own memory. Any time you say `new`, you need a corresponding `delete`.

Comment: ... but usually you can just say `drawLine(point1, Point(x, y));`. The expression `Point(x,y)` is a temporary object whose lifetime ends at the `;`.

Comment: I think you can do that with tuples, while in C++11 you can initialize structs as `drawLine(point1, Point{x, y});`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem isn't that you're trying to declare a struct as if it were a class (in fact, [there's very little difference between the two in C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/classes-and-objects.html#faq-7.9)).

The problem is that you're trying to construct a `Point` from two `ints`, and there ins't a suitable constructor. Here is how you can add one:

```
struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
   Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}
};
```

Comment: That way of initializing a struct is obsolete and will not compile with MSVC.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen there is nothing obsolete about the suggestion by NPE. all you need is a semicolon at the end of the struct's last bracket, but otherwise it is fine.

Answer (score 3):

`new` returns a pointer. Just `drawLine(point1, Point(x,y))` should work if you define the appropriate constructor for `Point`.

(`drawLine(point1, *(new Point(x,y)))` would also work, but would introduce a memory leak; every `new` should be balanced by a `delete`.)

Comment: When I try that, I get a very obscure "no suitable constructor exists from "int" to "Point". Specifically, I'm trying drawLine(point1, Point(x+1, y+2)), if relevant.

Comment: @woopf: Define the constructor as given by aix.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between struct and class in c++ is not that huge. Why don't you add a constructor to your struct?

Comment: By "not that huge", I think you mean that members of a struct are public by default, while members of a class default to private. It's important to understand how they *do* in fact differ, as opposed to just being aware that the difference is minimal. More details are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c).

Comment: @Cody Gray What's important to understand is that they don't really differ, except for some easily overridable defaults.  A `struct` still defines a class type, and can have all of the attributes of a class type (private members, functions, even virtual, constructors, destructors, etc.).  The choice between the keywords `struct` and `class` is purely one of convention and coding guidelines.

Comment: @James: Where did I argue differently?

Comment: @James, @Cody: I'd say dontomaso's point is just that "even though" it's [just] a `struct` it can still have a constructor, letting `woopf` know C++ structs aren't restricted to C-like features. Other details of the differences aren't relevant to this specific question.