# What can cause segmentation faults in C++?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I noticed there's not question with a list of common causes of segmentation faults in C++, so I thought I'd add it.

Naturally it's community Wiki, since there's no *one* correct answer.

I think this might be useful for newer programmers learning C++, feel free to close it if you disagree.

Comment: Uhm... looks like I can't move this to community wiki. Hopefully someone with more permissions comes along.

Comment: How about: "What _can_ cause segmentation faults in C++?". An embedded system without MMU won't give you any segfault at all - even when "writing" to the ROM.

Comment: You are correct, I'll change it.

Comment: I think I should add that you can get a segfault from a missing return (when a function should return a value, but you forgot to write the return for some reason). Spent about 1:30 debugging that...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Segmentation fault is caused by bad accesses to memory, only if your OS has a MMU ([Memory Management Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)). Otherwise, you won't get it but only strange behavior.

The virtual memory (the entire memory accessible to you = `2^(sizeof(pointer_type)*8)` (ie: `2^num_bits_in_pointer_type`)) is mapped to physical memory in units named pages or segments (paging superseded segmentation but they are still used).

Each page has some protection rights, if you try to read from a page with no-read access you'll get a segfault. If you try to write to a readonly location you'll get a SIGSEGV.

If you have an unitialized pointer and use it it may happen that it will point to another good location so you'll don't get a segfault. If you have a small array reading after it's bound may corrupt other memory areas if it doesn't get past the page boundary.

Also, since there are many pages, not all of them are really mapped. If you touch a non-mapped page you'll get a segfault. Actually, any access to a non mapped page will have to take into account copy on write, pages on swap, lazy loading, memory mapped files and other things. See [this article on page fault handling](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310172129/http://vistech.net/~champ/online-docs/books/linuxkernel2/060.htm), especially the second diagram there, posted here below too (but read the article for more explanations)

[image: page fault handling]
<sub>(source: [champ at vistech.net](https://vistech.net/~champ/online-docs/books/linuxkernel2/060_files/image002.gif))</sub>

You are mainly interested in what happens in user space and all paths leading to SIGSEGV. but kernel space is also interesting.

Comment: The link you have provided is useful but is it legit? I cannot read what I assume to be chinese so could you clarify the legal status? If it's all ok feel free to delete this comment.

Comment: Updated link with another resource on the same topic.

Answer (score 6):

Dereferencing NULL pointers.

```
#include <cstddef> //For NULL.
int* p1 = NULL; //p1 points to no memory address
*p1 = 3; //Segfault.
```

Comment: Where is your definition of `NULL`?

Comment: In `<stddef.h>`, and a couple of other headers.  In practice, it's probably included indirectly with most C++ headers, but it's best to be sure, and include `<stddef.h>` or `<cstddef>` anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I think my compiler includes it by default, I didn't know that others don't.

Answer (score 6):

Many of the ways to 'segfault' C++ aren't necessarily **guaranteed** to happen, in fact, that is the case with most of the examples posted here. It's merely good luck (or bad luck, depending on how you look at it!) if you can perform these operations without a segfault occuring.

That is actually one of the things in C++ that separates it from other languages; undefined behaviour. Whereas in Java or C# you might get an 'InvalidOperationException' or similar, which is guaranteed to happen when these operations are performed; in C++, the standard just says 'undefined behaviour', which is basically luck of the draw, and you never want that to happen.

Comment: So true about C++ and undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Accessing an array out of bounds (Possible):

```
int ia[10];
ia[10] = 4; // Someone forgot that arrays are 0-indexed! Possible Segfault.
```

Comment: No guarantee this will segfault.

Comment: @sharptooth - Uh, **possible** segfault then. Edited.

Comment: It is [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why).

Answer (score 3):

A favourite of mine:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    virtual void f() {
        std::cout << "A::f();\n";
    }
    int i;
};

struct B : A {
    virtual void f() {
        std::cout << "B::f();\n";
    }
    int j;
};

void seti(A* arr, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        arr[i].i = 0;
}

int main() {
    B b[10];
    seti(b, 10);
    b[3].f();
}
```

As with most things that can cause a segfault, this can also fail to fail.  On ideone, for example, `b[3].f()` fails, but `b[2].f()` works.

Comment: Hold on. Why would this segfault?

Comment: @fluffels - Simple answer:  it's UB, so it may.  Technically, it's because `void seti(A*, size_t)` overwrites the vtable of some elements `b`, which leads to any calls to virtual functions causing a segfault.  Or not causing a segfault, if they are miraculously overwritten to point to a function.  UB is UB.

Comment: Holy crap. Would this work properly with classes?

Comment: @fluffels - No.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is “undefined behavior”, but this begs
the question for an unexperienced programmer, and some types of
undefined behavior are much less likely to cause a segmentation fault
(or another type of crash) than others.  The most frequent causes of
segmentation faults are generally pointer related: dereferencing an
uninitialized pointer, a null pointer, or a previously freed pointer;
accessing beyond the end (or in front of the beginning, but that's less
frequent) of an object (array or other); using the results of an illegal
pointer cast (`static_cast` to a derived type, when the object doesn't
actually have that type, or most `reinterpret_cast`); etc.

Perhaps the most important point to keep in mind here, however, is that 
in general, these are not guaranteed to cause a segmentation fault, and
that often, the segmentation fault that they cause will only occur
sometime later, in a completely unrelated operation.  Thus, writing
beyond the end of a local array will usually “work”,
but will modify whatever happens to follow the array on the stack: some
other local variable (modifying the `vptr` of an object on the stack
may lead to a segmentation fault when you attempt to call a virtual
function on the object), the frame pointer of the calling function
(which will probably cause a segmentation fault in that function, after
you've returned), or the return address (which may cause all sorts of
strange behavior—a segmentation fault or an illegal instruction
trap are probably the best that can occur).  Writing beyond the end of
freed memory, or through an already freed pointer, can corrupt the free
space arena, causing a segmentation fault in a much (sometime much,
much) later allocation or free; it can also modify some other, totally
unrelated object, corrupting its `vptr` or some other pointer in the
object, or just some random data—again, a segmentation fault is
probably the best possible result (far preferrable to continuing with
corrupted data).

Comment: Indeed. You make a very good point regarding segfaults being preferable to corrupted data.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to modify string literals:

```
char* mystr = "test";
mystr[2] = 'w';
```

This **CAN** cause segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

Forgetting to initialize pointers, leaving them with random memory addresses. Note: this may not **always** segfault, but it could.

```
int* p1; //No initialization.
*p1 = 3; //Possible segfault.
```

Comment: No guarantee this will segfault. Maybe it will, maybe not.

Comment: Right again. I'm looking for examples of things that *could* cause segfaults, so I wasn't being specific enough. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing freed memory could potentially cause a segfault.

```
SomeClass* someObject = new SomeClass();
delete someObject;
someObject->someMethod();  //Could cause a segfault.
```