# my code does not run for the input 1 and 1000 or any other larger inputs

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

when i am trying to run this code for input 1 and 1000 it shows me segmentation fault .what will be the correction in this code ?

```
void sorting(int sum[],long int k);

int main() {
    int sum[100000]; 
    int L,R,i,j;
    long int k=0;

    cin>>L;

    cin>>R;
    for(i=L;i<=R;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<=R;j++)
        {
            sum[k]=i^j;
            k++;
        }
    }

    sorting(sum,k);

    cout<<sum[k-1];
    return 0;
}

void sorting(int sum[],long int k)
{
    int i,j;
    long int temp;
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<k;j++)
        {
            if(sum[i]<=sum[j])
            {
                temp=sum[i];
                sum[i]=sum[j];
                sum[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to narrow the problem down

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can cause segmentation faults in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923574/what-can-cause-segmentation-faults-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

The segmentation fault is caused by stack overflow. This line:

```
int sum[100000];
```

`sum` uses 400K spaces of stack, which is bigger than the normal size of stack.

To fix the problem, you can use `std::vector` to implement `sum` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is not in the stack size, but content of variable `k`

```
for(i=L;i<=R;i++)
{
    for(j=i;j<=R;j++)
    {
        sum[k]=i^j;
        k++;
    }
}
```

For `L = 1, R = 1000`, this loop makes `k` as large as `500500`, which exceeds the size of `sum` array, which has `100000` elements.

To dirty-fix this error you could make `sum` array larger, but, since stack size indeed can be limited, it's better to allocate huge arrays on a heap. This is also more elegant solution in your case, because you can dynamically set required size of the array.

To allocate memory on heap you can use `std::vector` or C++11 `unique_ptr<int[]>` (you could also use `new[]` and `delete[]`, although recently it is advised to use methods mentioned previously, because they secure some aspects of dynamic memory allocation).

To create array with `unique_ptr<int[]>`

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> sum = std::make_unique<int[]>(mysize);
//or if make_unique is not available
std::unique_ptr<int[]> sum(new int[mysize]);
```

It looks like you have arithmetic series, so you can calculate `mysize` using equations for the sum of arithmetic progression http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

With `std::vector` it can be less error-prone, because `std::vector` can grow, so you can simply `push_back()` elements inside the loop.

Define `sum` variable

```
 std::vector<int> sum;
```

Then inside the loop instead of `sum[k]=i^j;` you write

```
 sum.push_back(i^j);
```