# Programme crashes when I try to add data to struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a programme that adds new positions to structure list. Structure definition is:

```
struct data
{
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    float income;
    float taxed_income;
    char account[20];
    char id[10];
    struct data *next, *prev;
};
```

and function that adds data is :

```
struct data* add_element()

{
    struct data *tmp;
    bool flag=true;
    float input;
    char inpt[50];
    tmp = NULL;
    do {
        printf("Id: ");
        fgets(inpt,49,stdin);
        if(head != NULL)
            flag=id_check(inpt);
    }
    while(!flag);
    strcpy(tmp->id,inpt);
    do {
        printf("Name: ");
        fgets(inpt,49,stdin);
        flag=check(inpt);
    }
    while(!flag);
    strcpy(tmp->name,inpt);
    do {
        printf("Surname: ");
        fgets(inpt,49,stdin);
        flag=check(inpt);
     }
    while(!flag);
    strcpy(tmp->surname,inpt);
    do {
        printf("Account: ");
        fgets(inpt,49,stdin);
        flag=check_num(inpt);
    }
    while(!flag);
    strcpy(tmp->account,inpt);
    printf("Income: ");
    scanf("%f",&input);
    tmp->income=input;
    printf("taxed Income: ");
    scanf("%f",&input);
    tmp->taxed_income=input;
    return tmp;
}
```

programme crashes when I reach first strcpy. all checks are assuring that input meet project spec.

Comment: you never allocate memory for the struct, tmp just points at null and you write there which will crash the program

Comment: Please oh please try to format your code in a consistent and readable (for others) way. Consistent indentation and extra line-breaks makes wonders for readability (and therefore maintainability).

Comment: Try to allocate memory followed by snprintf function to copy string. This will work fine for you.

Comment: Again, we desperately need a canonical duplicate for "my program copies data into an uninitialized pointer why does it crash". If anyone got a better duplicate than [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923574/what-can-cause-segmentation-faults-in-c) please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer to the data structure that you created does not point to anything in memory since it points to NULL. Hence when you try to call the function `strcpy()` to copy data into the pointer, the program crashes since it is not copying the data to valid memory.

You might want to do some research into the function `malloc()` which allows you to allocate memory on the heap for your tmp ptr.

Something like this should suffice:

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
```

You should also check if the malloc() returned memory that you can use by adding the line:

```
assert(tmp != NULL);
```

Note: Don't forget to include the `<assert.h>` library.

Comment: you should not use `assert` for checking the return value of `malloc`:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/17732/3684343

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your have not allocated memory to the pointer to your structure.

`struct data *temp` can't take data in its fields unless your allocate it memory 
of the size of the structure as follows:

```
temp =  malloc (sizeof(struct data));
```

EDIT: 
Removed typecast for malloc

Comment: Everything except typecast helps.

Comment: @PaulR  dependent on compiler also. If using C++ compiler for `C` code, then typecast is needed.

Comment: Casting the return value of malloc will hide issues such as failure to include `stdlib.h` in your source file. It's a bad idea to do in C as a `void *` can be implicitly casted to any other pointer, so it's redundant.