# What happens if a pointer runs out of scope

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, segmentation-fault

I have the following code, and I am wondering why it works as it does:

```
void addFive(int* a) {
    int* b;
    b = a;
    *b = *b + 5;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int* nbr;
    *nbr = 3;
    addFive(nbr);
    std::cout << *nbr << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

This produces an output of 8.

I am wondering why? The pointer `int* b` runs out of scope at the end of the addFive function. Furthermore, `int* b` has no knowledge about the existence of `int* nbr` (one advantage of smart pointers). I expected the code to create a segmentation fault in the line `std::cout << *nbr << std::endl;`

Why does this code not give a segmentation fault?

Comment: `int *nbr; *nbr = 3;` you're accessing random memory which you don't own. The example has UB.

Comment: Uninitialized pointers = Undefined Behaviour.  You never make `nbr` point at anything, either.

Answer (score 1):

Function `addFive` is normal by itself but it should be written like this:

```
void addFive(int* a)
{
   *a += 5;
}
```

And there is no any problem with pointer's `b` scope because pointer itself is just a local variable.

Real problem in your code is that you didn't allocate memory for your integer and trying to access uninitialized memory through pointer `nbr` which leads you to undefined behaviour. On my machine I have segmentation fault at this line:

```
*nbr = 3;
```

Your main should be rewritten like this:

```
int* nbr = new int(3);
addFive(nbr);
std::cout << *nbr << std::endl;
return 0;
```

Then you can reliably expect '8' in your output.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this code not give a segmentation fault?

Your expectation for *segmentation fault* is correct. But all random accesses of memory won't create segmentation fault. If the randomly accessed memory have any [protection rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection) then only it creates *segmentation fault*. If it do not have any protection then you can access the memory without any problem but with an [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because you could not assume the contents in the random memory. A good pictorial explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6923764/5756174).