# c++ code: class or structure: difficult to understand

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

I am looking at somebody header file for a structure, but it looks like functions are a part of this structure... so then this is a class but how to abstantiate? or use?

```
struct Recording
{
    FLAG mode;  
    unsigned short intervals;   
      unsigned short saved_cycles;                                      
    virtual void SavetoFile( FILE *file, 
        bool Control, 
        PhaseData *__phaseData = NULL   
        );

    virtual bool LoadfromFile( FILE *file, 
        bool Control, 
        PhaseData *__phaseData = NULL 
        );
};
```

Comment: A structure is a class in C++ - just use it like any other class.

Comment: @jdl: Are you asking if this is a class or struct, or is your question   "how to abstantiate? or use?" If the latter, what do you mean/what does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ `class` and `struct`are identical, except that the default access specifier for the former is `private`, while for the latter it is `public`.

```
class Base { /* .. */ };

class Foo : Base
{
  int i;
};

struct Bar : Base
{
  int i;
};
```

In the above code, `Foo` inherits privately from `Base` while `Bar` does so publicly. Similarly, `Foo::i` is private while `Bar::i` is public. Note that the visibility of `i` in both cases has nothing to do with inheritance i.e. it'd be the same even if `Foo` and `Bar` did not inherit from `Base`.

Other than these differences, everything that you can do with one, you can also do with the other.

Comment: is it true they used to be very different but over time they have become almost identical? (with reference to C struct's)

Comment: Much better answer than my concise version :)

Comment: @Flyphe I'm not aware of any such difference ever having existed

Comment: @Flyphe: A `struct` in C++ is not the same as a `struct` in C. However, a `struct` in C++ that is POD (plain old data, no functions/constructors/constructed members/etc.) is compatible with its counterpart `struct` in C.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the only meaningful difference between a `class` and a `struct` is that variables and functions of a `class` are private by default, and of a `struct` they are public by default.

Answer (score 0):

All subobjects (members AND bases) are private by default when using the `class` keyword, public by default with `struct`, and both define a class type.

Answer (score 0):

The features are struct are that:

All members are public by default.
Inheritance is public by default, i.e. if a struct inherits from a class or a struct it is public.

With a class both of the above are private by default, i.e. if you oo not specify others.

With regards to data members, this makes it compatible with C (where structs can only have data members) which means you can use your C structs in C++ too.

There are occasions where, even in C++, structs are still used, but my own preference is generally to use the word "class" unless I specifically want all my data members public, which happens on occasion where you are simply grouping them together.

The code posted would probably benefit from private data members, as well as const-correctness and possibly making the virtual methods abstract. Also would need a virtual destructor as it has virtual methods.

In addition you should not be using identifiers beginning with two underscores unless you are implementing "the system".