# Difference between a struct and a class

Tags: c++, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

I've done my homework and had diverse answers on Google.
Some say structs do not have inheritance, some say structs do not have access specifiers, while others say they have both.
Could someone clarify then, the differences between a struct and a class in C and C++, and also the difference between a struct in C & C++.

Comment: For one, there are no classes in C.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In C++, the only difference between a struct and a class is that struct members are public by default, and class members are private by default.

*However*, as a matter of style, it's best to use the `struct` keyword for something that could reasonably be a struct in C (more or less POD types), and the `class` keyword if it uses C++-specific features such as inheritance and member functions.

C does not have classes.

C structs cannot use C++-specific features.

**EDIT**:

The [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/), question 7.9, has this to say:

> The members and base classes of a `struct` are `public` by default,
>   while in `class`, they default to `private`. Note: you should make
>   your base classes *explicitly* `public`, `private`, or `protected`,
>   rather than relying on the defaults.
>
> `struct` and `class` are otherwise functionally equivalent.
>
> OK, enough of that squeaky clean techno talk. Emotionally, most
>   developers make a strong distinction between a `class` and a `struct`.
>   A `struct` simply *feels* like an open pile of bits with very little
>   in the way of encapsulation or functionality. A `class` *feels* like a
>   living and responsible member of society with intelligent services, a
>   strong encapsulation barrier, and a well defined interface. Since
>   that's the connotation most people already have, you should probably
>   use the `struct` keyword if you have a class that has very few methods
>   and has `public` data (such things *do* exist in well designed
>   systems!), but otherwise you should probably use the `class` keyword.

And quoting Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language", 4th edition, section 16.2.4:

> These two definitions of **S** are interchangeable, though it is
>   usually wise to stick to one style. Which style you use depends on
>   circumstances and taste. I tend to use **struct** for classes that I
>   think of as "just simple data structures." If I think of a class as "a
>   proper type with an invariant," I use **class**. Constructors and
>   access functions can be quite useful even for **struct**s, but as a
>   shorthand rather than guarantors of invariants.

Comment: -1 style point is opinion and highly debateable

Comment: @JohnDibling: Yes, it's an opinion.  Do you have any support for a different opinion?

Comment: Structs don't have inheritance then?

Comment: @Siddhartha: Sure they do.  As a matter of style (*in my opinion*) they shouldn't use inheritance, but they can.

Comment: Almost all of MS's STL code uses structs pretty much everywhere for meta-programming. I would guess that the reason is that it incurs less typing, as most functors only have public members. Given that almost all code I see has the public members at the top of the class definition anyway, I think that the `class` keyword should really just have been a `#define class struct`.

Comment: +1 right to the point. The recommended style is nice too

Comment: Structs "feeling" like bags of bits aside, I posit that no professional C++ programmer worth his salt will be thrown by a structure having methods and private data. Or at least they should not.

Comment: @JohnDibling: By all means post an answer stating your opinion.  I'm not saying that a programmer should be "thrown" by such a struct, just that, in my opinion, it should have been declared as a `class`.  Yes, it's just an opinion (style issues generally are) -- but I believe it's an opinion shared by most C++ programmers.

Comment: @JohnDibling: (I've *finally* gotten around to looking this up) -- it appears that Stroustrup mostly agrees with me. I'm not claiming that that settles the question, but I think it does suggest that it's a reasonable preference.

Comment: @KeithThompson:  Wow, diggin' up an medium-oldie.  While I do not challenge the validity of your opinion, or that of Our Holy Father, I *still* do not agree with the style point.  My stance is somewhat different, though admittedly not space-alien different from yours.  I didn't feel like I had the energy to enter in to this debate years ago, so didn't post a dissenting answer.  Perhaps I will now.  In the meantime, I *do* think it's reasonable for me to revert my downvote as your opinion is completely valid in my view.

Answer (score 3):

In C, classes do not exist. In C++, structs have a default access specifier of `public`, while classes default to `private`.

There are several differences between structs in C and C++; in C++ they can inherit from other classes or structs, they can contain member functions, and their names don't need to be referred to with an elaborated type specifier.

Comment: kk so structs do inherit..from other classes and structs? how bout if a class tries to inherit from a struct?