# Difference between struct and class when Template meta-programming

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

```
template<int n>
struct Numberim{
     enum{ value = Numberim<n-1>::value + n };
};

template<>
struct Numberim<0>{
     enum{ value = 0 };
};
```

this is a simple tmp example,and it's ok;

```
template<int n>
class Numberim{
     enum{ value = Numberim<n-1>::value + n };
};

template<>
class Numberim<0>{
     enum{ value = 0 };
};
```

I use g++ to compile,and it complains...however, as far as I know, struct and class is treated nearly in the same way.just like this"In C++, the only difference between a struct and a class is that struct members are public by default, and class members are private by default."

So, what's the difference between them here in earth?

Comment: `it complains.`- how does it complain?

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference?

Comment: @Jesse   the g++ says like this "error: ‘Numberim<22>::<anonymous enum> Numberim<22>::value’ is private", well...I think I am naive to ask this question.Thank you.

Comment: @stuser974349: The answer is in your question: `class members are private by default`, I don't understand the confusion. @josephthomas: You probably meant `class's` not `struct's`.

Comment: stuser974349: that is because struct's are public by default. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference will be same as it would be for typically class vs struct. Your "value" will be public for your first example (using struct) and private for your second example (using class).

For a reference on the difference between a class and a struct, please see [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Concrete class `Numberim<1>` is not related to concrete class `Numberim<0>`.

Thus, having one class refer to the other’s definition of `value` works when `value` is `public`, which it is for the `struct`, but not when `value` is `private`, which it is for the `class`.

You can use the `friend` mechanism, or you can make `value` public, or you can, much more simply, do this:

```
template<int n>
class Numberim{
    enum{ value = n*(n+1)/2 };
    // And whatever else you want in here. 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is still the same, when it tries to compile `Numberim<n-1>::value` with `n=1` it tries to use the template specialization. However, since `value` is `private` member of `Numberim<0>` (as the class member variables are `private` by default) it gives the compiler error.