# struct and class and inheritance (c++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

Could you ensure me, if all access specifiers (including inheritance) in `struct` are `public` ?

In other words: are those equal?

```
class C: public B, public A { public:
    C():A(1),B(2){}
    //...
};
```

and

```
struct C: B, A {
    C():A(1),B(2){}
    //...
};
```

Comment: You could have tested this yourself with a very small program.

Comment: Check this thread out about the differences between classes and structs in c++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c

Comment: @Nobody: But then he'd rely on his compiler not having bugs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf), 11.2.2, page 208:

> In the absence of an access-speciﬁer for a base class, public is assumed when the derived class is declared struct and private is assumed when the class is declared class.

So yes, you are correct: when the derived class is a `struct`, it inherits other classes as `public` unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they all are public.

```
struct A : B {
  C c;
  void foo() const {}
}
```

is equivalent to

```
struct A : public B {
 public:
  C c;
  void foo() const {}
}
```

For members, it is specified in §11:

> Members of a class defined with the keyword class are private by default. Members of a class defined with the keywords struct or union are public by default.

and for for base classes in §11.2:

> In the absence of an access-specifier for a base class, public is assumed when the derived class is defined with the class-key struct and private is assumed when the class is defined with the class-key class.

where the references are to the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 2):

From the C++11 Standard ([N3242 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/))

> 11.2 Accessibility of base classes and base class members
>
> 2 In the absence of an access-specifier for a base class, public is
>   assumed when the derived class is defined with the class-key struct
>   and private is assumed when the class is defined with the class-key
>   class.