# structure vs class

Tags: c++

Today, I was curious to find some of differences between a structure and a class, in C++. So, I found some of the differences:

1. In a structure, by default members are public while private in class.
2. Inheritance in case of a structure is public by default, while private in case of class.
3. Classes can take part in templates, while structures cannot.

click here to see that a **struct** cannot be used in place of **class** in case of **template.**
http://ideone.com/p5G57

```
template<struct T> void fun(T i)
{
    cout<<i<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i=10;
    fun<int>(i);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the errors:

```
prog.cpp:4: error: ‘struct T’ is not a valid type for a template constant parameter
prog.cpp: In function ‘void fun(T)’:
prog.cpp:4: error: ‘i’ has incomplete type
prog.cpp:4: error: forward declaration of ‘struct T’
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘fun(int&)’
```

However, if **struct** is replaced with **class**, it works perfectly. see here: http://ideone.com/K8bFn

Apart from these above differences, when I replace `class` with `struct` in my code, the code works perfectly without making any further changes.

Now, I want to know, **are there more differences, that I am missing and I should know?**

Comment: *Classes can take part in templates, while structures cannot* **false**. Where did you take this idea from? You cannot use the keyword `struct` as an equivalent to `typename` in template arguments, but that is just the keyword.

Comment: @David Rodríguez, i have updated the post. please see it

Comment: @algogeek class in templates is just a keyword. Nothing to do with an actual class (like already stated in my answer).

Comment: So yes, you can't use **the keyword struct** in a template declaration, but you can use a `struct` to specialize a template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's no other difference, **but** the third one you specify isn't correct:

> Class can take part in template while structures cannot.

In case of templates, the `class` keyword is just syntactic sugar, it doesn't mean the type has to be an actual class. Generally, programmers prefer `typename` for basic types and `class` for classes or structs, but that's just by convention.

Other than that, you can use both `class` and `struct` to specialize templates.

Comment: +1, I use `typename` always, and the coding conventions where I work dictate `class` always, which makes for an interesting clash... it is hard not to write what you are so used to. Using one or the other to hint on purpose might lead you to *see* purpose where there isn't.

Comment: I use `class` always. That way if I have to use `typename` for its other meaning in a template parameter declaration it's more readable. Besides, `class` is easier to type.

Answer (score 4):

There are two main differences:

- In absence of an access-specifier for a base `class`, public is assumed when the derived class is declared `struct` and private is assumed when the class is declared class.
- Member of a class defined with the keyword class are private by default. Members of a class defined with the keywords `struct` or `union` are public by default.

Comment: Is this a quote? What's the source?

Answer (score 1):

A struct is just a class with all members public by default.

According to The C++ Programming Language (3rd ed.), section 10.2.8:

> By definition, a struct is a class in which members are by default
>   public; that is
>
> ```
> struct s{ ...
> ```
>
> is simply shorthand for
>
> ```
> class s { public: ...
> ```

Then he goes on to say:

> I usually prefer to use struct for classes that have all data public.
>   I think of such classes as "not quite proper types, just data
>   structures."

**Edited per the comments**:

In section 15.3.2 it says:

> The access specifier for a base class can be left out. In that case,
>   the base defaults to a private base for a *class* and a public base
>   for a *struct*.

Comment: I believe it's wrong, since the two are not equivalent. There's also a difference in inheritence access level.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Well, those two *are* equivalent, but `struct S : Q { ` is "shorthand" for `class S : public Q { public:` so the "shorthand" cannot really be inferred from the example.