# c structure doesn't allow static member while c++ does

Tags: c++, c

Today, i was a little bit surprised about the behavior of **c structure vs c++ structure**.

fun.cpp: http://ideone.com/5VLPC

```
struct nod
{
    static int i;
};

int main()
{

    return 0;  
}
```

The above program works perfectly.

BUT,

When the same program is run in **C** environment, it is giving the error:

```
prog.c:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘static’
```

see here: http://ideone.com/2JRlF

**Why it is so?**

Comment: How would you define it? C has no scope resolution operator.

Comment: Uhm... so different language are *different*? How come?

Comment: Because tautologies are tautological?

Comment: Huh? Maybe...because..C doesn't allow static members? It's just a feature C doesn't have, there is no certain *why* to it. You could also try to define a class, namespace or operator overload in C and ask *"why it not work?"*. It's just a different language with different features, that's it.

Comment: It's just that `static` isn't defined this way in C. You can, however, define it yourself to make it work: just `#define static`, and off you go! (No, of course I'm not serious!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in C++, structs are just classes with default visibility of `public`. So in C, the struct is only a aggregation of data, which does not know anything about the fact that it could  be percieved as standalone type.

See also [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

Each C++ class has its class namespace, so you can refer to that static data member as `nod::i` from outside the class namespace, and just plain `i` inside it. C has no namespace scopes, and there's no code "in" C structs, so there's no way to hide globals in namespaces or to refer to them by their unqualified name in their own scope. So there was no motivation in C to have the thing that in C++ is called static data members.

Just do `int nod_i;`.

Answer (score 3):

`static` in C **only** has the meaning of internal linkeage. Don't think of a C-`struct` as you would of a `struct` or a `class` in C++. It's just an aggregator, not the OOP construct.

As C doesn't have classes, this use of `static` doesn't make sense.