# Using public keyword with struct

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, access-modifiers

Is there a difference between:

```
struct B {...}; 
struct D : B {...};
```

and:

```
struct B {...};  
struct D : public B {...};
```

If no, why everyone, including the standard, using more verbose, 2nd variant?

Comment: people are using the second way, so they use the same way in class in structs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

Comment: Actually, the standard has examples of the 1st variant, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the two are exactly the same. And I am not sure everyone uses the second variant. I don't, for instance. Neither does the standard use it everywhere. For example, in C++11 §3.8, we see this:

```
struct D1 : B { void f(); };
```

On the other hand, being explicit means that people who don't know the rules can understand the code.

Answer (score 4):

No, because with structs, both default access specifier and default type of inheritance is `public`. Speaking of that, default access specifier for classes is `private`, and that's the only difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ in context of declaring types.

As for "why" - probably because it's a bit more explicit and one doesn't need to remember the difference between `class` and `struct` in that matter.

Comment: "and that's the only difference between struct and class in C++" in the context of struct/class declarations. There is an unrelated difference, which is that `class` has another meaning related to templates, which `struct` doesn't.