# Why structure is lightweight and Class is Heavyweight in C++

Tags: c++

Please tell me difference and also why??

Comment: It's not. A `struct` is a `class` where everything is public by default, that's the only difference. Or a `class` is a `struct` where everything is private by default, either way.

Comment: @down-voters - well, the statement is completely wrong, but this is not Prasad007's fault. I don't think it deserves that many down-votes.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c/92951#92951

Comment: @KirilKirov But even the most basic research could have revealed the answer. I didn't downvote, but I do think it's justified.

Comment: @delnan - you may be right. I wouldn't down-vote anyway, but you have a point, really :)

Comment: Friends I heard above line from my professor and i didn't get that that's y i asked you...But still m confused!!   So Plz tell me on what basis i can say struct is lightweight and class is heavyweight...I'm Student so plz help me.....

Comment: It sounds like you should ask your professor to clarify their statement. The distinction of "lightweight" or "heavyweight" isn't part of the language or common usage among programmers.

Comment: Guys why u people r giving me down vote, i was confused that is why i asked you..Now I'm not able to post another Question...Thanks for good answers...

Answer (score 6):

> Why structure is lightweight and Class is Heavyweight in C++

Who said that? That is entirely an incorrect statement.

The difference between struct and class is that the *default* accessibility for `struct` is `public`, whereas for `class` it is `private`. Otherwise, `struct` is same as `class`.

Comment: This *looks* like "comment, not an answer", but I couldn't have phrased it better :-)

Comment: Now, I hope it *looks* like an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Because of how programmers' brains work.

`struct` comes from C, where it originally had no methods, access levels and other `class`-specific stuff that C++ brought along. There's also the default `public` access level it has in C++ that makes it more of a container of some members, rather than a full-on OOP object.

`class` on the other hand was introduced by C++, and provides all of the above (and `private` access level by default).

Of course, there's no difference (other than default access level) in C++ between the two, so it's mostly a *meta* way of saying light-weight and heavy-weight. When you say `class`, you inherently think of methods, private members, polymorphism and inheritance. When you say `struct` you think that it has 2 `int`s as members & that's it :)

Comment: *a meta way of saying light-weight* Nice :-)

Comment: I've been trying to figure out whether this answer is saying anything, but I can't help but think it's sheer personal opining and emoting. In particular, "rather than full-on OOP object" just sounds plain misleading...

Comment: @KerrekSB it's largely subjective, yes, but if you look at large codebases, you'll see it's true. Otherwise, why would there be snippets like `class X{public: ...};` instead of `struct X{...};`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Same reason that there are lots of `getFoo()` and `setFoo()` functions and huge inheritance hierarchies -- it takes a long time for a language to develop its idioms, and programmers can be very resistant to changing habits!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question. Maybe you are asking about "virtual" things. There is a possibility to have virtual table in the Classes/structures in C++. You cant memset them, it will cause a lot of problems. Virtual Table cost you extra memory so maybe that is why they are "heave"...

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/how-vtables-work/

Also remember that Struct and Class in C++ is the same expect  that struct has public fields and functions by default.