# C++ pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: c++11, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

I keep getting this error. I know what function causes it, but don't know how to fix it. Looking up online from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257916/pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-for-pointer-assignment) saying:

> You need to pass a pointer to a dynamically allocated object, or make your own insde your chainLink class.

However, as I try to pass a string pointer. error still popping up. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MWTNode.h"
#include "MWT.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
MWT t;
string str ="abc";
string* strPtr = &str;
t.insert(strPtr);
std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
return 0;
}


#include "MWTNode.h"
class MWT {
public:
MWTNode *root;
string find(const string &);
void insert(const string* string);

};
void MWT::insert(const string* word) {
MWTNode* curr = root;
MWTNode newNode;
string w = *word;
for (int i = 0; i < word->length(); i++) {
    const char c = w[i];
    if (curr->children.find(c) == curr->children.end()){

        //curr->children[c]= MWTNode();
        //node->frequency=node->frequency+1;
    }
    curr = &(curr->children[c]);
}
curr->flag = true;
}



#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class MWTNode {
public:
unordered_map<char, MWTNode> children;
string value;
bool flag;
int frequency;

MWTNode(const string &);
MWTNode(const char c);
MWTNode();
void setFrequency ();
int getFrequency ();

};


MWTNode::MWTNode(const string &val) {
value = val;
flag = false;
frequency = 0;
}

MWTNode::MWTNode(const char c) {
value =c;
flag = false;
frequency = 0;
}

MWTNode::MWTNode() {
value ="";
flag = false;
frequency = 0;
}
```

Comment: The pointer is useless, as you copy the string it points to and never use the pointer again.

Comment: After trimming the chatty material, your title is "C++ pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug". Is this an error message? Where is it from?

Answer (score 1):

Lets highlight a few lines of the code you show

```
class MWT {
public:
MWTNode *root;
// ...
};
```

In that you declare the member variable `root` as a pointer.

```
void MWT::insert(const string* word) {
MWTNode* curr = root;
// ...
}
```

In the above you make `curr` point to where `root` is pointing.

***But*** you never make `root` point anywhere! The `MWT::root` variable is *uninitialized* and will have an *indeterminate* value. Using this pointer in any way without initialization will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

And yes you use this pointer, as you dereference `curr` inside the `MWT::insert` function.

It's a little unclear what you're doing (to me) but you need to make sure that `root` (and therefore `curr`) is a valid pointer before attempting to dereference it.

Comment: I am trying to implement multiway trie using unordered_map, so I created a MWTNode class and MWT class. then trying to create a MWT by calling its inert? which part is not clear, please let me know if you would suggest a diff way to do this?