# How to create a struct and initialize it at the same time?

Tags: c++

The struct is defined like this:

```
 struct Edge {
    int weight;
    Vertex* v1;
    Vertex* v2;
  };
```

I need to do something like

```
new Edges(v1, v2, v3);
```

but that could only be done with a "class" and using ctor. How can I create a new element of struct and initialize it at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: Why use `new` at all? Anyway, you're looking for aggregate initialization.

Comment: I tried to do something like v[v1].edges.push_back(new Edges(v1, v2, v3)); and edges is defined as list<Edge*> edges;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a constructor for a `struct` as well in C++. A C `struct` is very limited, but in C++ there exists only [2 differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c) between `struct` and `class`.

1. In `class` all members are by default `private`, in `struct` all members are by default `public`.
2. Inheritance from `struct` defaults to `public` while `class` defaults to `private`

Thanks @gil_bz and @icepack

Comment: To be more specific, there is NO difference between structs and classes in C++, besides the default accessibility for members (public for structs, private for classes)

Comment: And default inheritance from `struct` is `public` instead of `private` for `class`.

Comment: Your differences between `struct` and `class` are not completely right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a parameterized constructor. Do it this way

```
struct Edge
{
    int weight;
    Vertex* v1;
    Vertex* v2;

    Edge(int a_weight, Vertex *a_v1, Vertex *a_v2)
    {
        weight = a_weight;
        v1 = a_v1;
        v2 = a_v2;
    }
};
```

Then create object like this:

```
Edge e(9, v1, v2);
```