# Needed: C++ class for maintaining a 1-dimensional list of extents

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl-algorithm

I am looking for a C++ class that can maintain a 1-dimensional list of extents.

Each extent is defined as a `(start,len)` pair.

I want to be able to add additional extents to the list and have them automatically consolidated. That is, if we have `(0,5)` and `(10,5)` in the list, and `(5,5)` is added, the new list should contain only `(0,15)`.

Extents are never removed from the list.

Does anything like this exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are looking for Boost.Icl. It does exactly what you described.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html

Comment: It's not clear to me if the Boost.lcl will combine adjacent extents. Do you know for sure that it does? We're going to have hundreds of thousands of contiguous extents.

Comment: Yes it will. I use it in this way all the time. Check this page:http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html#boost_icl.introduction.interval_combining_styles

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example implementation of a simple interval container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;
using std::pair;
using std::make_pair;

typedef pair<int, int> interval;    

struct interval_container
{
    void add(int start, int len)
    {
        _data.emplace_back( make_pair(start, len) );
    }

    void consolidate()
    {
        // sort intervals first by start then by length
        std::sort(_data.begin(), _data.end());

        // create temp data
        vector<interval> consolidated;

        // iterate over all sorted intervals
        for(const interval& i : _data)
        {
            int start = i.first;
            int len = i.second;

            // special case: first interval
            if (consolidated.empty())
            {
                consolidated.emplace_back(i);
            }
            // all other cases
            else
            {
                // get last interval in the consolidated array
                interval& last = consolidated.back();
                int& last_start = last.first;
                int& last_len = last.second;


                // if the current interval can be merged with the last one
                if ((start >= last_start) and (start < (last_start + last_len)))
                {
                    // merge the interval with the last one
                    last_len = std::max(last_len, (start + len - last_start));
                }
                // if the current interval can't be merged with the last one
                else
                {
                    consolidated.emplace_back(i);
                }
            }
        }

        // copy consolidated data
        _data = consolidated;
    }


    vector<interval>& data() { return _data; }

private:
    vector<interval> _data;
};


int main()
{
    interval_container intervals;

    intervals.add(0, 2);
    intervals.add(1, 3);
    intervals.add(5, 3);

    intervals.consolidate();

    int c(0);
    for(interval i : intervals.data())
    {
        std::cout << (c++) << ": from " << i.first << " to " << (i.first + i.second) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Question --- I've seen a whole bunch of people defining classes with `struct`, as you have here, rather than with a proper C++ class declaration. Why define a class as a structure?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c) for a SO question regarding the differences between struct and class. Personally, I do it because I always declare public methods on top of the class and I don't want to always type 'public:'. With time it has became an habit.