# Defining functions in Structs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, struct

I have known that structs in C doesn't support functions / constructors like a class in C++ . However I did try putting in function definitions and constructors and the code behaved as if I have defined a class and not struct . I used visual studio 2010 for my code . Is this a standard feature or just that it works only with MS C++.
I searched many forums and they had mixed responses .

Answer (score 1):

In C++ Structs and Classes are the same except for one thing. A class' members and methods are private be default, a Struct's are public by default.

Comment: And `struct` inheritance is public by default. And the `struct` keyword cannot be used in template parameter declarations.

Answer (score 1):

`struct` and `class` are functionally the same in `C++` except members in a `struct` are public by default and in a `class` are private by default. in fact this [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c) covers it in itty bitty details.

If you compiled successfully than you must have been using `C++`.

Comment: yeah thats right , I did use C++ , but was confused about the behaviour . I thought the C part in C++ should behave as it is. But does it also mean that it could be replacement for the classes in C++ . Like achieve everything from it as we would have by using a class

Comment: @Prashant C++ behaves differently from C in too many ways to describe here, you can use `struct` instead of `class` but most people will only use `struct` for very simple objects. Please read the link I provided it has some great commentary on when to use either one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard feature of C++ but not of C. You must have been compiling in C++.