# Embed different functions in a function: functor or lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functor

I am writing a program in C++ that I should embed different functions into a same `for` loop.

Examples:

```
for(i = 0; i < N_ITER; i++) {
    /* ... */
    function_A(); 
    /* ... */
}

for(i = 0; i < N_ITER; i++) {
    /* ... */
    function_B(); 
    /* ... */
}
```

---

For performance consideration **I must inline `function_A` and `function_B`** into this function. My first solution is using Functors and function templates as follows:

```
class function_A {
public:
    void operator()() {
        /* ... */   
    }
};

class function_B {
public:
    void operator()() {
        /* ... */
    }
};

template <class T>
class run {
public:
    void operator()() {
        /* ... */
        T func;
        for (i = 0; i < N_ITER; i++) {
            /* ... */
            func();
            /* ... */
        }
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

And I can call the functions like:

```
run<function_A>()();
run<function_B>()();
```

But soon I found that there's too much duplicated functor definations `class xxx { public: void operator()() {...} };` in code and it looks awkward.

---

So I turned into a solution using lambda:

```
auto function_A = []()
{
    /* ... */
};

auto function_B = []()
{
    /* ... */
};

template <class T>
class run {
public:
    T func;
    run(T func) : func(func) {}
    void operator()() {
        /* ... */
        for (i = 0; i < N_ITER; i++) {
            /* ... */
            func();
            /* ... */
        }
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

But this time its harder to call these functions:

```
run<decltype(function_A)> funcA(function_A); funcA();
run<decltype(function_A)> funcB(function_A); funcB();
```

And it is not as clear as the previous solution.

---

It there a more elegant way to implement it in C++? Am I missing something?
Any suggestions would be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
void run(std::function<void(void)> fn)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N_ITER; i++)
        fn();
}

(...)

auto lambda1 = []()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    };

run(lambda1);
```

After preparing such `run` function / method, you'll be able to do this as well:

```
class C
{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        printf("Hello world from a functor!\n");
    }
};

(...)

C c;

run(c);
```

---

**Edit**: In response to comments:

The previous solution was not inlined. However, this was:

```
template <typename T>
void run2(T fn)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        fn();
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    getchar();

    auto lambda1 = []()
        {
            std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
        };

    run2(lambda1);

    getchar();
}
```

Disassembly:

```
        auto lambda1 = []()
            {
                std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
            };

        run2(lambda1);
002E1280  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[2E3044h]  
002E1286  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (02E1730h)  
002E128B  dec         esi  
002E128C  jne         main+10h (02E1280h)
```

Actually, the solution with functor in case of run2 was also inlined, though a little bit longer:

```
    C c;

    run2(c);
01031293  mov         esi,0Ah  
01031298  jmp         main+30h (010312A0h)  
0103129A  lea         ebx,[ebx]  
010312A0  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[1033044h]                          \
010312A6  mov         edx,10331ACh                                         |
010312AB  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (01031750h)  > loop 
010312B0  dec         esi                                                  |
010312B1  jne         main+30h (010312A0h)                                 /
```

Comment: I know this solution. I am just not sure whether the lambdas will be compiled as inlined functions since performance is a very critical consideration here.

Comment: @Naruil I modified my answer.

Comment: A clever solution. I should have thought of that. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your concern

> But soon I found that there's too much duplicated functor definations
>   `class xxx { public: void operator()() {...} };` in code and it looks
>   awkward.

you should probably not be writing

```
class function_B {
public:
    void operator()() {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

but the version with `struct` where you save one line of syntactic clutter (`public:`) because members of structs are by default public:

```
struct function_B {
    void operator()() {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

which really, IMO, has rather little overhead compared to a simple function declaration.

Of course, the lambda version has a little less, and [combined with a free templeate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17229343/321013), you also don't need `decltype`.

Wrt. to the lambda solution, one also must take into account that you *can* put the whole definition of the `struct` into a header file, while you *cannot* put the definition of the lambda *object* in a header file, if that header file is used from multiple translation units.

Of course the problem as stated rather looks like these definition would most likely be written inside a `cpp` file, so the lambda solution probably would works just as well.

Comment: -1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c

Comment: @Spook - yeah, exactly. `struct` is default public, which is what the OP wanted. Where is the problem?

Comment: He doesn't mind the public modifier, but the huge amount of unnecessary duplicated classes. Changing class into struct won't help.

Comment: @Spook: Nice to see you knowing what the OP minds and what not.

Comment: "But soon I found that there's too much duplicated functor definitions in code and it looks awkward." ? Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: @Sppok: Yeah, so I removed one line of the duplicated code -- which, given that the overhead vs. a normal function definition was 3 lines, now down to 2 lines, is a reduction of a swooping 33% in boilerplate.

Comment: If function had 100 lines, it now would have 99, so effectively the gain is minimal. I guess the problem is, that classes are used to mimic the functions and that's the problem with quality of code. I removed the -1, but still, changing class to C-style struct is not a solution here.