# What was the reason for including the 'class' keyword in C++, when there already was 'struct'?

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct

This just occurred to me while writing a struct for my project, instead of a class:

With just one significant difference between structs and classes as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c), what was the main reason to include the 'class' keyword in c++?

Has it been included for its comparativeness to other major object-oriented languages, Java for e.g.?

Comment: simple answer:because C have struct

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested on how C++ got the way it is until about '95, read [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html). The keyword was added quite early, when more plans were open. LAter the difference stayed as it is today.