# Defineing a Typedef? (UDP Packet)

Tags: c++, typedef, packet

I'm using RakNet to create a program which involves networking. I however don't know how to define a typedef for a Packet. The function I am trying to get it working for is:

```
void UDP_ClientDisconnected(Packet *pPacket);
```

Packet needs to be a typedef for this function obviously, however I don't know how to do this? Thanks to anyone who offers a solution.

**Edit:**

```
void Connections::UpdateRakNetwork()
{
for(Packet = Peer ->Receive(); Packet; Peer ->DeallocatePacket(Packet), Packet = Peer ->Recieve())
{
    PacketID = GetPacketIdentifier(Pacekt);

    switch(PacketID)
    {

        case ID_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION:
            UDP_ClientDisconnected(Packet);
            break;
    }

    Peer ->DeallocatePacket(Packet);
}
}
```

Information is passed from this Packet sorting also in Connections.cpp, to the .h file in order to allow me to access these features from other elements of the game. Therefore allowing me to call `UDP_ClientDisconnected(..);` from another file.

As of yet there is no errors with this part of the file but the .h declaration, with the "Packet is not a Type name" error. As the guy below suggested it might be the fact that I named something else packet therefore I renamed it RakPacket and gain the same error.

Comment: `Packet` does not *obviously* need to be a `typedef`. Maybe you can explain why it needs to be one.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams how should templates help out here?

Comment: I'm fairly sure Packet is an interface - and that you have to inherit from it. Look in the header file defining class Packet - see if it has virtual methods make a class which implements these virtual methods - and pass it as `pPacket`.

Comment: Because Visual Studio keeps moaning at me sayin when I hover over the error: "Connections::Packet" is not a type name.

If its now this how should I define packet?

Comment: @Iwan Sorry I didn't understand that :(

Comment: please be more specific. whats the error? what's the line the error is happening?

Comment: void Connections::UpdateRakNetwork()
{
 for(Packet = Peer ->Receive(); Packet; Peer ->DeallocatePacket(Packet), Packet = Peer ->Recieve())
 {
  PacketID = GetPacketIdentifier(Pacekt);

  switch(PacketID)
  {
   case ID_NEW_INCOMING_CONNECTION:
    Packet_NewIncommingConnection(Packet);
    break;

   case ID_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION:
    Packet_PlayerDisconnected(Packet);
    break;

   case ID_CONNECTION_LOST:
    Packet_ConnectionLost(Packet);
    break;
  }

  Peer ->DeallocatePacket(Packet);
 }
}

Comment: Information is passed from the Type of packet to that function for further processing, this will be used to display things such as Steve has Joined the Server.

Comment: you also can edit your post.

Comment: from your previous answer, Packet seems to be a object (variable), not a class definition.

Comment: @user1591117 - I downloaded RakNet - cant find UDP_ClientDisconnected anywhere in the package - can you please indicate what header provides UDP_ClientDisconnected - and maybe pastbin it somewhere and give the link.

Comment: I just updated the post, sorry its late but my lectrics went out. Also the UDP_ClientDisconnected is a custom declared function in order to alllow me to access these packet statements from other files.

Comment: @TomasBadan so Packet needs to be a Class?

Comment: Maybe you should begin with some easier program in C++. It seems that you are not familiar with Oriented Object Programming in C++. Take a look at : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ It is a good begginning...

Comment: @Pierre I've been doing fine upto this point, I havn't had to look at any tutorials as I have done some OOP before. This is what I'm stuck on and oncce its reolved and I know why. I can then continue. I have actually noticed I DO point it to a struct (RakNet::Packet *RakPacket I did alter it earlier and I still continue to get this error. If no solution is foind I will still continue with this

Comment: @user1591117 in the function declaration, `Packet` could be a class/struct, but it could also be a typedef to a builtin type (unlikely, but cannot be ruled out). In your `Connections::UpdateRakNetwork()` definition, `Packet` looks like the name of a variable. So it has a different meaning in the two code samples you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is the solution :

```
void Connections::UpdateRakNetwork()
{
    RakNet::Packet *RakPacket = NULL;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    for(RakPacket = Peer->Receive(); NULL != RakPacket; Peer->DeallocatePacket(RakPacket), RakPacket = Peer->Recieve())
//      ^^^^^^^^^                            ^^^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^
    {
        RakNet::PacketID pID = GetPacketIdentifier(RakPacket);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                       ^^^^^^^^^

        switch(pID)
        {

            case ID_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION:
                UDP_ClientDisconnected(RakPacket);
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^
                break;
        }

        Peer->DeallocatePacket(RakPacket);
//                             ^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

**I'm not helping you by giving you that. Again try to understand `RakNet::Packet *RakPacket = NULL;` and why we are not using the classname as a parameter of a function but the pointer to an object...**

**EDIT :**

In response of the first comment :

> In C++, an object is a region of storage with associated semantics. In the context of the object model of C++, the term object refers to an instance of a class. A class defines the characteristics of its instances in terms of members: data members (state) and member functions (methods or operations), and the visibility of these members to other classes. C++ is statically typed.

In this explanation you can replace the word `class` by `struct`. The only difference between both is the default access right to their members (`private` for `class` and `public` for `struct`) : [What are the differences between struct and class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c).

Comment: RakNet::Packet is an Object.. its a struct.

Comment: @user1591117 I would say it is a type. For example, `RakNet::Packet p` here p is an object of type `RakNet::Packet`. I edited my post for an explanation...

Comment: Okay... I'll do some reading up on this part however I seem to understand nost things I've since come accross. I actually have a working Game Engine I plugged into the Client and everything; I started this in order to just see how far I can get, and I was refusing to be beaten at Server Sided RakNet. 

Thanks btw :D.

Answer (score -2):

You can this easily by writing:

```
typedef Packet * pPacket;
```

After that you can create a pointer to a Packet object via:

```
pPacket somePacket(NULL);
somePacket = new Packet(...);
//etc...
```

Typedef's are great, but hiding pointers makes it unreadable. So if you really want to do that, you better have a good reason for this.

**EDIT:**

```
"Connections::Packet" is not a type name.
```

Make sure that you include the correct classes and libraries. Is that your only compiler error?

Comment: do you really think this will solve the problem if the function looks like `void UDP_ClientDisconnected(Packet *pPacket);`?

Comment: I trided changing it to

Comment: @itwasntpete. No probably not. But he asked how to do it and so I told him how. I don't think his problem is related to the typedef keyword in anyway. That's why I asked more questions.