# Can structures in C++ have functions inside?

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct

While reading a book, I came across these lines :

> There is very little syntactical difference between structures and classes in C++ and, therefore, they can be used interchangeably with minor modifications. The only difference between structure and a class is that, by default, the members of a class are private,while, by default, the members of structure are public.

However, my teacher told me that  we cannot have functions inside structures. The book I've read is quite popular and I think that what written on it is correct. 
Is it possible to have functions inside structures ? If yes, kindly leave an example or reference link.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong. However, the book is also not quite right; in addition to default access being public for `struct`s, default inheritance is also public.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you!

Comment: Well, you have two options: change the teacher or buy another book (about C this time, but keep the other)... ;). Jokes apart, maybe your teacher was explaining the differences betwen C and C++ (good idea) or his course is intended to start with a brief tour about the C language and after then he will introduce C++ (not really a good idea IMHO).

Comment: @Bob__ I asked my teacher to clarify my doubt and showed and example program. She said, "You'll get the output but you're not supposed to do that. Never do that again. " Also, she gave me three differences one of which is "Classes can contain both functions and variables but structures can only contain variables." . It is only C++ and C is never introduced to us.

Comment: Your teacher needs a teacher. As all the answers pointed out, in C++ structs can have member functions as those are nothing less then classes with default public visibility for members. Maybe it's a matter of style convention for her, but the rules are clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A C `struct` cannot have member functions. (It can have *function pointers*, which however are not the same thing.)

A C++ `struct` is equivalent to a `class` in every way but the default visibility of its members, as stated by your book (`public` for `struct`, `private` for `class`), and its default inheritance.

---

```
class MyClass : public BaseClass
{
     public:
         MyClass();
         virtual ~MyClass();

         void someFunction();

     private:
         int member_;
};
```

In the above example, which does state visibility (`public`, `private`) explicitly instead of relying on defaults (a practice I endorse, for clarity), the keyword `class` could be swapped for `struct` without any change of meaning or result.

There is some understanding that `struct` is preferred for plain data collections, while `class` is preferred for fully-fledged classes with non-trivial functionality, but that is as far as it goes.

---

Perhaps your teacher was talking about **C** `struct`s.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. We don't have C at school only C++. Can you give me a example program so that I can show it to my teacher ?

Comment: @HGSur: Any piece of C++ with member functions in it, really. If you always give visibility explicitly instead of relying on the default (as you should, for clarity), `struct` and `class` are just interchangeable keywords.

Comment: so struct something{private : <body> } is equivalent to class ?

Comment: Thanks again. Now I understand struct can do anything a class can do with some keywords :)

Answer (score 2):

An example with method in struct:

```
#include <iostream>

struct HelloWorld {
    void operator()() const
    {
        std::cout << "hello world\n";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    HelloWorld{}();
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/LQrU2x)

Answer (score 1):

`struct`s in C++ are basically `class`es. Hence, they can have member functions. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c) for more information on the difference between both.

> However, my teacher told me that we cannot have functions inside
>   structures.

That's correct when speaking about C. C only allows data to be stored in a `struct`. Best thing you can do is store a function **pointer** in a `struct`.