# Overloading () operator inside structure in cpp

Tags: c++

I came across the following code in a project.

```
map_erase_if(cfgIp.m_raw, RawCreate());
```

I understand that this will call the function defined by () inside the   structure.

The Rawcreate is a structure which is given below .

```
 struct RawCreate {  
         bool operator()(const Device::StoreElm& el) {  
             Pcap* pcap = NULL;  
             pcap = Pcap::findServer(el.second->name());  
             if (!pcap) {  
                 try {  
                     MEM_NEW(pcap,Pcap(*el.second));  
                 } catch (Exception& ex) {  
                     MAND_LOG(DBG_SIPTCP, "Error:%s", ex.what());  
                 }  
             }  
             for (RejItr itr = CfgIp::m_rejectList.begin(); itr !=   CfgIp::m_rejectList.end(); ++itr) {
                             if(ip_equal(itr->first, pcap->getInterface(),   false) && !itr->second.empty()) {  
                                 pcap->blockReg();  
                              }  
                          }  
             if (pcap) {  
                 MEM_DELETE(el.second);  
                 return true;  
             }  
             return false;  
         }  
     };
```

I have seen operator overloading with class objects.I know class and structure   has only few differences in cpp.But using overloading  within a structure in   this way is a new thing for me.Can any one clarify its usage?

Comment: this post will help you to understand : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c, so no difference except default access-specifier

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class Basically, `struct` and `class` denote the same entity.

Comment: `RawCreate()` doesn't call `operator()`. It just creates an instance of that type. It's possible that `operator()` will be called from inside the `map_erase_if` function which you haven't shown.

Comment: In the map_erase_if   the RawCreate() is used as a predicate for std::find_if

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RawCreate()
```

> I understand that this will call the function defined by () inside the structure.

If `RawCreate` is a function, then this will call it. If it is a type, then it will construct an instance. `RawCreate` is a class, so the latter is true. `T::operator()` is *not* called by this expression.. unless `RawCreate` is a variable of type `T` that defines the operator.

> I know class and structure has only few differences in cpp

Just to clarify, the only difference is that classes declared with the `struct` keyword and those declared with `class` keyword have a different [access specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) by default.

> Can any one clarify its usage?

The documentation of `map_erase_if` should describe how the operator is used. Presumably, the `operator()` of the functor is used as a predicate for erase.

Comment: And if it's a variable with an `operator()` it will call that operator ;)

Comment: @TartanLlama oh, yea.. and you could actually create an instance `RawCreate RawCreate` just to piss off your co workers :)

Answer (score 1):

`RawCreate()` creates an instance of `RawCreate`.

Your code works like this code:

```
RawCreate c;
map_erase_if(cfgIp.m_raw, c);
```

but avoids creating an unnecessary variable.

Presumably, `map_erase_if` is then going to call the instance's `operator()` with each member of `cfgIp.m_raw` (or pass the instance on to something that does).

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, `RawCreate()` does not call the `operator ()`, it just creates an instance (which is then copied over).

The `operator ()` is then (most likely) called for each item of the map when iterating during `map_erase_if()` (and if the operator returns true, the item will be erased, if the function works as the name advertises).