# Can we implement all the concepts of OOPS using the keyword struct?

Tags: c++, oop, struct

Can we implement all the concepts of OOPS using the keyword struct?
The answer from  [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_interview_questions.htm) is YES!
But I don't understand how?
Please Tell!

Comment: In c++ a struct **is** a class with a couple of tweaks. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c

Comment: which OOP concept that you can implement with `class` but unable with `struct`?

Comment: Actually my son during his initial course of CS in the University implemented a complete OOP system in pure C :-)

Comment: can't really do it in C++ either. member functions fall very short of message sending.

Comment: Well you have to use some other keywords as well, e.g. `const`, `virtual`, `private` etc. in order to implement all OO concepts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A struct is a class, only all attributes/methods are public by default in the struct. You can very well have methods and attributes in a struct.
You can also inherit from a struct (default inheritance is public).

So basically, yes, you can use struct to build an OOP.

Answer (score 0):

With a C struct no!
The key concept to OO is polymorphism.

To consider a language to be implementing OO you need a runtime dispatch of messages or function calls. In c++ this is implemented by using the `virtual` keyword.

**Now this might well be a trick question as struct and class in c++ only differs by default visibility of members.**

Comment: The struct can carry an set of function pointers.   Derived classes simply over ride those methods.   Polymorphism can be implemented with pointer to structure.

Comment: @EvilTeach That is a silly argument. Any language can call   `member(this, object_functions, arguments).`  An OO language comes from language primitives.  You can write OO in C as well as ASM and brainfuck.