# What is the difference between enum struct and enum class?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Looking at the [`enum` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), there was one thing that I noticed:

> ***enum-key*** - one of `enum`, `enum class`(since C++11), or `enum struct`(since C++11)

`enum` and `enum class`, sure, but what is a `enum struct`?

The docs seem to say that `enum class` and `enum struct` are exactly the same:

> [...] *scoped enumeration* (declared with the *enum-key* `enum class` or `enum struct`)
>
> ---
>
> - `enum struct`|`class` *name* `{ enumerator = constexpr , enumerator = constexpr , ... }`
> - [...]

Are they really exactly the same? Or are there any differences that I missed? What is the point (if they are the same) to have 2 different syntax for the same thing?

Comment: What is the point of not including both syntax? It makes sense to just have both given that struct and class are usually equivalent (apart from public/private) in c++.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`enum class` and `enum struct` are the same (emphasis mine).

> **7.2 Enumeration declarations**
> ...
>   <sup>2</sup> .... The *enum-keys* `enum class` and `enum struct` are ***semantically equivalent***;
>   an enumeration type declared with one of these is a *scoped enumeration*, and its *enumerators* are *scoped
>   enumerators*.

Answer (score 27):

> `enum class`, sure, but what is a `enum struct`?

Same as `enum class`.

> Are they really exactly the same?

Yes. The documentation is correct.

> Or are there any differences that I missed?

No. There are no differences.

> What is the point (if they are the same) to have 2 different syntax for the same thing?

I haven't found any written rationalization for the decision. There isn't any in the standard nor the proposal. One might guess that it is some sort of counterpart to `class` vs `struct` class-keys. This is an opposite decision than was made when `template<class T>` syntax was specified, where `struct` is not allowed.

Comment: But `template<typename T>` is allowed, and is also equivalent to `template<class T>`!
The standard is quite confusing on these 2 points, isn't it?

Comment: @ZeeByeZon: No. `class` and `struct` being near synonyms in type declarations is common. The only difference is the default public/private access of their members. Since scoped enums have no private members, the only difference between the two is meaningless.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not just members. It also affects inheritance.