# Scala Case Classes - Are they just structs?

Tags: scala, struct, case-class

So I just learned about scala case classes, and I'm told they are used to provide a simple wrapper around a bunch of properties so that it's easier to test for equality. But now I have two questions:

- Is this just the same thing as a struct in C++/C#?
- Are case classes a value type or a reference type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First note that a `struct` in C++ and a `struct` in C# are very different things.

- Structures in C++ are just like regular classes but by default, their members
  are public. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c) for more on this topic.
- Structures in C# are value types. When passed as a parameter, they are 
  copied instead of passed via a pointer. This behaviour is similar to a 
  primitive type in Java. This behaviour is the default in C++, with any 
  `class` or `struct`.

Your second question has been answered in Eric's answer but the important point is that C# structures are passed completely by value (all their fields are copied) while Java/C# classes are passed via a pointer (that is passed by value). See [this famous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) if you want the full explanation.

Unfortunately, it is not currently possible to have a true value type in JVM bytecode. You cannot make your own type that will be fully copied everytime you pass it. And the answer is no, case classes aren't value types like C# structures. A JVM language may try to replicate the behaviour of a value type but it will be managed by the GC and passed via a pointer (that is passed by value).

To give a more direct answer, no:

> Case classes are like regular classes with a few key differences.

Learn more about them on [this page](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html).

Comment: I would avoid saying "deeply" copied because that might imply the wrong thing when talking about `struct`s that hold pointers in C++. It's technically a "shallow" copy. :)

Comment: @ErichGubler Indeed, fixed the mistake.

Answer (score 7):

Not really. What scala case classes are most like is ... scala classes.

They actually *are* regular scala classes with a few additional methods, that get added to them automatically - namely, `.copy` on the class itself and `.apply` and `.unapply` on the companion object. They also get a nice `.toString` method, listing all the fields, and `.equals`, that compares instance members rather than the object ref.

In most other respects, they are just regular scala classes.

Comment: They also get a default hash method.

Answer (score 2):

Scala classes are just like Java classes. Their *reference* is passed by value.

Scala *case* classes are just like scala classes, but some things are automatically generated for you:

- The fields of the constructor are publicly accessible (albeit a case class is immutable by default, thus you can regard them as `public final` values in Java, unless you declare the fields of the case class as `var`)
- An `equals` and `hashCode` method based on the fields of the constructor
- An `apply` and `unapply` method in the companion object
- A `toString` method showing all the values of the constructor
- A `copy` method

Here's an example:

```
case class MasterOfTheUniverse(name: String, power: Int)

scala> MasterOfTheUniverse("He-Man", 100).name
res1: String = He-Man

scala> MasterOfTheUniverse("He-Man", 100).power
res2: Int = 100

scala> MasterOfTheUniverse("He-Man", 100).toString
res3: String = MasterOfTheUniverse(He-Man,100)

scala> MasterOfTheUniverse("He-Man", 100) == MasterOfTheUniverse("She-Ra", 90)
res4: Boolean = false

scala> MasterOfTheUniverse("She-Ra", 90) == MasterOfTheUniverse("She-Ra", 90)
res6: Boolean = true

scala> MasterOfTheUniverse("He-Man", 100).copy(name = "He-Manatee")
res7: MasterOfTheUniverse = MasterOfTheUniverse(He-Manatee,100)
```

Comment: Case classes are not necessarily immutable, although they can be  `case class X (var x:Int);
  val xs = X(1) ;  xs.x = 2; println(xs.x)    //> 2`