# Do struct have better performance over classes in embeded system

Tags: c++, c++11, arduino

Is it true substituting structs with classes will generate or cause performance penalty in embedded systems dealing in areas where memory and efficiency are required
The reason for asking this is due to the fact that i am experiencing a drop in performance after adding some new libraries.
If structs and classes are practically the same then why i am getting a performance drop

Comment: There's no such thing as "structs" in C++. There are only classes (and unions and built-in types.) `struct` is a keyword that can be used to declare and define classes.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c Not sure if this question can simply be closed as a duplicate, or if this needs some citations to support "no, there's nothing more than that".

Comment: The only difference between `struct` and `class` is whether members default to private or public. This only affects visibility at compile time, it has no runtime implications at all.

Comment: @juanchopanza this is a valid point but I struggled to understand why to this was happening in my scenario until i realized that some compilers old one do tend to this, If the platform is slow enough

Comment: Classes and structs are data structures, with different default access protections.  They both can lead to better performance, they can contribute to execution slowness.  You can't do one-performance-fits-all because the data structures will differ depending on their usage.  A struct for a point is different than a struct for a USB packet.