# Array of structs inheriting interface appear to be reference types

Tags: c#, struct

I have a struct called `Foo` and `Bar` - both if these implement an interface called `IFoo`.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string StrTest { get; set; }
    int NumTest { get; set; }
}

public struct Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo(string backTest, int numTest)
    {
        StrTest = backTest;
        NumTest = numTest;
    }

    public string StrTest { get; set; }
    public int NumTest { get; set; }
}

public struct Bar : IFoo
{
    public Bar(string backTest, int numTest)
    {
        StrTest = backTest;
        NumTest = numTest;
    }

    public string StrTest { get; set; }
    public int NumTest { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I have an array of `IFoo`, at index "0" I have a `Foo` struct. The problem comes when I move that struct over to a new index - such as "1" (which **should** copy it). Now, you would expect both of them to be separate, meaning you change one and the other ***shouldn't*** change as well.

However, I find that if I change one of the properties for the newly moved one - both change... isn't this `class` (reference type) functionality?

Take a look at the following example:

```
// Create a list of "BackInterface"s - with foo and bar.
List<IFoo> arr = new List<IFoo>
{
    new Foo("A", 2),
    new Bar("B", 4)
};

// Now, place the SAME struct at index "0" (the foo) at the end - it should be copied?
arr.Add(arr[0]);

// Modify the item at the last newly-created index
arr[2].StrTest = "C";
```

Both `arr[0]` and `arr[2]`'s `StrTest` are now `"C"`.

If I have an array of just `Foo` or `Bar` I don't have this problem - only when I have an array of `IFoo`. I have also tried normal arrays (of type "`object`) and `ArrayList` (which doesn't have generics) - none of which have worked.

Any idea what is happening in here, *and how to still be able to have an array of both `Foo` and `Bar`, both having to have an implementation of something?*

Comment: Mutable structs are evil.  Avoid them at all possible costs.

Comment: Read up on boxing.  E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032750/structs-interfaces-and-boxing

Comment: In order to dispatch an interface method, boxing is required. You could for example have also created a class implementing `IFoo`.

Comment: Note a struct doesn't inherit from an interface, it implements an interface.

Comment: @Servy Just asking: What is particularly bad about mutable structs?

Comment: @ABPerson There's lots of readily accessible information on the topic.  Just do some searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an array of both Foo and Bar, both structs, without the boxing you're seeing.

You get boxing if you cast a struct to an interface, which happens when you create List<IFoo> and then put your struct in it.  You can see your structs have become reference types by doing

```
bool test = arr[0].GetType().IsValueType;
```

after you create arr: it will be false for List<IFoo> and true for List<Foo>.

There are some workarounds, such as having two arrays one for Foo and one for Bar and then another array to index into both of them.  But that's horrible.  See [this earlier Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163446/4166522) for more.

Because of all this in general it's not a great idea to put interfaces on structs: structs are intended to be lightweight things that live on the stack.  If you need this behavior you're better off using classes.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as the answer since it does go into a bit more detail - as well as *possible* workarounds - but, I guess I'll just stick with a class! Even if I will have to clone it *a lot*.

Answer (score 1):

By storing the value types in a variable that's of an interface type it gets boxed.  Interfaces are always reference types, so implicitly converting a value type implementing it to the interface's type needs to box it.  A boxed value type is a reference type, so you're observing reference type behavior because `arr[0]` *is in fact a reference type*.