# Best DataStructure for HighPerformance Seek in c#

Tags: c#, list, generics, search, data-structures

I was wondering which data structure would offer me better performance for my scenario....
My requirements are:
Possible Huge DataSet several million of records, I am going to write it only once and I am not going to change it any more during the execution lifetime, I don't need that it is stored in a sorted way....
I was thinking to go with List but if I use a Linq query and in the where condition call InRange performance are very bad... if I do a foreach, performance are not so great.... I am pretty sure that there is a best way to do it ( I was thinking to use a struct and or implement IEquatable but performance are not improving...
witch is the quickest data structure in C# for querying in my range with optimal performances?
What I want is a data structure to store several million of instances of the class Rnage

```
class Range
{
    public int Low {get; set;}
    public int High {get; set;}    
    public bool InRange(int val) { return val >= Low && val <= High; }
}
```

A logic example would be List but I am afraid that List class is not optimized for my requirements... since it is sorted and I don't need sorting and it affect a lot on performances...

thanks for the help!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What kind of data is stored in the dataset? And what kind of operations are you doing with the dataset? Also I don't really understand what you're Range class has to do with the question, perhaps you could explain you're code a little more.

Comment: You should reword your question, it's not very clear what you're trying to do. From what I understand, you have a collection of Range objects, and you want to find the ones for which InRange returns true, right?

Comment: yes Thomas you are correct... I was thinking to use a List<Range> to store several millions of Ranges but when it comes to performances, it perform very bad... so I need an other way to store my class (or eventually change it in a struct) more optimized for my requirement:

Comment: Is there anything special about the type of data that can help optimize the algorithm?  For example, if it was ranges of ages, knowing that the numbers are between 0 and 130 can help.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot think about nothing to optimize it...

Comment: Low is smaller than High and the operation that I have to do is to check how many times my items are contained in the range...

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want an interval tree.  Stackoverflow user alan2here has recently asked several [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476840/alan2here?tab=questions&sort=newest) regarding a project he's working on; Eric Lippert pointed him towards the interval tree structure in [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8765772/385844).