# Equals and GetHashCode confusion

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to implement an immutable `Point` class where two `Point` instances are considered equal if they have the same `Coordinate`s. I am using Jon Skeet's [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6151660/465056) of a `Coordinate` value type.

For comparing equality of `Point`s I have also inherited `EqualityComparer<Point>` and `IEquatable<Point>` and I have a unit test as below:

Point.cs:

```
public class Point : EqualityCompararer<Point>, IEquatable<Point>
{
    public Coordinate Coordinate { get; private set; }

    // EqualityCompararer<Point>, IEquatable<Point> methods and other methods
}
```

PointTests.cs:

```
[Fact]
public void PointReferencesToSamePortalAreNotEqual()
{
    var point1 = new Point(22.0, 24.0);
    var point2 = new Point(22.0, 24.0);

    // Value equality should return true
    Assert.Equal(point1, point2);

    // Reference equality should return false
    Assert.False(point1 == point2);
}
```

Now I am really confused by the 3 interface/abstract methods that I must implement. These are:

- `IEquatable<Point>.Equals(Point other)`
- `EqualityComparer<Point>.Equals(Point x, Point y)`
- `EqualityComparer<Point>.GetHashCode(Point obj)`

And since I have overriden `IEquatable<Point>.Equals`, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx) I must also implement:

- `Object.Equals(object obj)`
- `Object.GetHashCode(object obj)`

Now I am really confused about all the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods that are required to satisfy my unit test (Reference equality should return false and value equality should return true for `point1` and `point2`).

Can anyone explain a bit further about `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

Comment: Easy way to explain the relationship: if `a.Equals(b) == true` then `a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode()`, if `a.Equals(b) == false` then `a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode() || a.GetHashCode() != b.GetHashCode()`

Comment: This I understand, but my question is why the interfaces / abstract classes? How should I implement them to keep them in line?

Comment: You don't need to implement `IEqualityComparer`, that is only for external classes to be passed in as a special case comparer. A good example: the [various string comparers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for things like ignoring case. `IEquatable` is so you don't need to box your struct inside a `object` to do the comparisons, if you are using a class instead of a struct you don't really need IEquatable either.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I implemented `EqualityComparer<T>` because I used collections in my other classes consuming `Point` (e.g. when I call `IEnuermable<Point>.Distinct()` it will use my comparer instead of the default one)

Comment: What you do is make the default behave the way you want. EqualityComparer is only when you want non default behavior for comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Coordinate already implments `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(Coordinate)` for you it is actually quite easy, just use the underlying implmentation

```
public class Point : IEquatable<Point>
{
    public Coordinate Coordinate { get; private set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Coordinate.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as Point);
    }

    public bool Equals(Point point)
    {
        if(point == null)
            return false;

        return this.Coordinate.Equals(point.Coordinate);
    }
}
```

the `IEquatable<Point>` is unnecessary as all it does is save you a extra cast. It is mainly for `struct` type classes to prevent the boxing of the struct in to the `object` passed in to `bool Equals(object)`.

Comment: However when I have an `IEnumerable<Point>` and call `Distinct` on it, it returns duplicated elements where the `Coordinate`s are equal. Do I need to use `EqualityComparer<Point>` in this case?

Comment: Never mind. Figured out myself. You are right. Accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):
Used to check if two objects are equal. There are several checks for equality (by value, by reference), and you really want to have a look at the link to see how they work, and the pitfalls when you don't know who is overriding them how.

[GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):
A hash code is a numeric value that is used to insert and identify an object in a hash-based collection such as the Dictionary class, the Hashtable class, or a type derived from the DictionaryBase class. The GetHashCode method provides this hash code for algorithms that need quick checks of object equality.

Let's assume you're having two huge objects with heaps of objects inside, and that comparing them might take a very long time. And then you have a collection of those objects, and you need to compare them all. As the definitions say, GetHashCode will return a simple number you can compare if you don't want to compare the two objects. (and assuming you implemented them correctly, two different objects will not have the same hashcode, while objects who are supposed to be "equal" will).

And if you want Jon Skeet's opinion on something similar, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411500/understanding-iequatable).