# std::map default value for build-in type

Tags: c++, default-value, stdmap

Recently, I was confused by the std::map operator[] function.
In the MSDN library, it says: "If the argument key value is not found, then it is inserted along with the default value of the data type."
I tryed to search much more exactly explanation for this issue. For example here:
[std::map default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333728/stdmap-default-value)
In this page, Michael Anderson said that "the default value is constructed by the default constructor(zero parameter constructor)".

Now my quest comes to this:"what the default value for the build-in type?". Was it compiler related? Or is there a standard for this issue by the c++ stardard committee?

I did a test on visual studio 2008 for the "int" type, and found the "int" type is construted with the value 0.

Comment: I did a test with "bool" type. And there is something freaky: when i use "bool b = new bool()", the value of b turns out to be 0; but when i use "bool *pb = new bool[10]; pb[0] = new bool();" and then the pb[0] turns out to be 1, the oppositive value. Oh, I did this test on visual studio 2008.

Comment: When you wrote `pb[0] = new bool();`, `new bool()` is a *pointer*, whereas `p[0]` is a bool. A pointer can be implicitly converted to `bool`, and gives the result `false` if the pointer is a null pointer, `true` otherwise. So the true value you observed just tells you that `new` didn't return a null pointer (which of course plain `new` never does anyway). Also, you leaked the allocation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is defined in the standard, yes.  map is performing "default initialization" in this case.  As you say, for class types, that calls a no-arguments constructor.

For built-in types, in the '98 standard, see section 8.5, "Initializers":

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a non-POD ...
> - if T is an array type ...
> - otherwise, the storage for the object is zero-initialized

And, previously,

> To zero-initialize storage for an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a scalar type, the storage is set to the value 0 (zero) converted to T

Scalar types are:

- Arithmetic types (integer, floating point)
- Enumeration types
- Pointer types
- Pointer to member types

In particular, the behaviour you see with an integer (initialized to zero) is defined by the standard, and you can rely on it.

Comment: I just checked this in the C++11 standard, and it says something different. It says that if the type isn't a class or an array, then _no initialization is performed_. So I'm unsure about the default values in the standard containers now.

Comment: The quotes from the obsolete standard are misleading because a lot of POD instances do not get default-initialized, by default. The default, even in C++98, for POD types is to not initialize them at all. The terminology was cleaned up (and made horrendously complex) with C++11. Only value-initialization reliably zero-initializes.

Answer (score 24):

The C++11 standard still requires that std::map zero-initializes built in types (as did the previous standard), but the reasons are a bit different to those in Luke Halliwell's answer. In particular, to 'default-initialize' a built-in data type *doesn't* mean zero-initialize in the C++11 standard, but rather it would mean 'do nothing'. What actually happens in `std::map::operator[]` is a 'value-initialization'.

Nevertheless, the end result in the new standard is the same as in Luke's answer. The values will be zero-initialized. Here are the relevant parts of the standard:

Section 23.4.4.3 "map element access" says

> T& operator[](const key_type& x);
>
> Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map.
>
> ...

The expression `T()` is described in section 8.5

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be **value-initialized**.
>
> `X a();`

And this kind of 'value-initialization' is described in the same section

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T
>     is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible
>     default constructor);
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if
>     T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that
>     constructor is called.
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.**

Answer (score 6):

The default value of class-type objects is that set by the default constructor of the class. For built-in types the default value is 0.

But note that there is a difference between a built-in variable that isn't initialized, and one initialized to its default value. A built-in that is not initialized will probably hold whatever value was in that variable's memory address at the time.

```
int i;          // i has an arbitrary undefined value
int x = int();  // x is 0
```

Comment: Outdated link above. See here: http://www.stroustrup.com/glossary.html . Not sure how it helps

Comment: Nope. For built-in types the default value is not defined. The default constructor of built-in types does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

```
 |expression:   | POD type T                               | non-POD type T
 ==================================================================================================
 | new T         | not initialized                          | default-initialized
 | new T()       | always default-initialized               | always default-initialized
 | new T(x)      | always initialized via a constructor     | always initialized via a constructor
```

As far as i know, stl uses new T() for default values, so it will be default-initialized, in case of int to 0.

Comment: `new T() ` implies value initialization. Value Initialization is different from Default Initialization.

Comment: new T() implies value initialization? What's the difference between value initialization and default initialization when I use new T()?

Comment: @WKPlus The difference is that if T is not a class type, to *default-initialize* means **no initialization at all**. Reading such a value is actually UB.