# Is a default value of nullptr in a map of pointers defined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11, big-o, time-complexity

The following code seems to always follow the true branch.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class TestClass {
  // implementation 
}

int main() {
  std::map<int, TestClass*> TestMap;
  if (TestMap[203] == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "true";
  } else {
    std::cout << "false";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Is it defined behaviour for an uninitialized pointer to point at `nullptr`, or an artifact of my compiler?

If not, how can I ensure portability of the following code? Currently, I'm using similar logic to return the correct singleton instance for a `log file`:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>    

class Log {
  public:
    static Log* get_instance(std::string path);
  protected:
    Log(std::string path) : path(path), log(path) {};
    std::string path;
    std::ostream log;
  private:
    static std::map<std::string, Log*> instances;
};

std::map<std::string, Log*> Log::instances = std::map<std::string, Log*>();

Log* Log::get_instance(std::string path) {
  if (instances[path] == nullptr) {
    instances[path] = new Log(path);
  }
  return instances[path];
}
```

One solution would be to [use something similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2333816/1691346) where you use a special function provide a default value when checking a `map`. However, my understanding is that this would cause the complexity of the lookup to be `O(n)` instead of `O(1)`. This isn't too much of an issue in my scenario (there would only ever be a handful of logs), but a better solution would be somehow to force pointers of type `Log*` to reference `nullptr` by default thus making the lookup check `O(1)` and portable at the same time. Is this possible and if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The map always value-initializes its members (in situations where they are not copy-initialized, of course), and value-initialization for builtin types means zero-initialization, therefore it is indeed defined behaviour. This is especially true for the value part of new keys generated when accessing elements with `operator[]` which didn't exist before calling that.

Note however that an uninizialized pointer is *not* necessarily a null pointer; indeed, just reading its value already invokes undefined behaviour (and might case a segmentation fault on certain platforms under certain circumstances). The point is that pointers in maps are *not* uninitialized. So if you write for example

```
void foo()
{
  TestClass* p;
  // ...
}
```

`p` will *not* be initialized to `nullptr`.

Note however that you might want to check for presence instead, to avoid accumulating unnecessary entries. You'd check for presence using the `find` member function:

```
map<int, TestClass*>::iterator it = TestMap.find(203);
if (it == map.end())
{
  // there's no such element in the map
}
else
{
  TestClass* p = it->second;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Just for further clarification, would "TestClass* p();" be initialised to nullptr?

Comment: @MrBushido No. `TestClass* p();` doesn't declare a variable, it declares a function taking no parameters and returning `TestClass*`.

Comment: MrBushido: `int *p;` is default-initialized so has indeterminate value. `int *p{};` is zero-initialized and 0 converted to a pointer is always the null pointer constant so will compare equal to nullptr.

Comment: The answer is using the wrong terminology. The `std::map` will *value-initialize* (not *default-initailize*) a new element in `operator[]` if it did not exist. It is important to note the difference, as *default-initalization* of POD types leaves them *uninitialized*, while *value-initialization* means *zero-initialization* for those same types. Replacing *value-initialization* where *default-initialization* appears in the answer will make it right.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Did they change that terminology for C++11? Because I'm pretty sure that in the old standard "default-initialization" was defined as zero-initialization for PODs. A quick search [comfirms my memory.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4524064/1032073)

Comment: @celtschk: After rechecking the standard (both C++03 and C++11) it seems they changed the definition of *default-initialize*. What has not changed is that map *value-initializes* in both standards, in the new one it is explicitly said, in the old one through the semantics of `operator[]` being equivalent to `(*((insert(make_pair(x, T()))).first)).second`: `T()` is value initialization of an object of type `T`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I don't think the term "value-initialize" even existed in the old standard, and the old description of "default-initialize" matches the behaviour of `map` (to zero-initialize the value, or to call the default constructor where applicable). Nevertheless I'll change the used term in my post to match the current standard.

Comment: Trust me, I just checked *both* standards. In C++03 the description of `T()` is in 5.2.3p2 *The expression T(), where T is a simple-type-specifier (7.1.5.2) for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates an rvalue of the specified type, which is value-initialized *. The same quote in C++11 reads *The expression T(), where T is a simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier for a non-array complete ob- ject type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates a prvalue of the specified type,which is value- initialized*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: OK, I now did a search for the term "value initialized" and found out that it was [introduced in C++03.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1613578/1032073) I hadn't been aware of that change; my knowledge about those terms came from C++98.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's defined behaviour. If an element isn't yet in a map when you access it via `operator[]`, it gets default constructed.