# Count how many times each distinct word appears in its input C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Enter input: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    std::map<std::string, int> m;
    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it;
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    std::string words;

    do {
        iss >> words;
        it = m.find(words);
        if(it != m.end())
        {
            m.insert(it, std::pair<std::string, int>(words, m[words] + 1));
        }
        else
        {
            m.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(words, 1));
        }
    }while(iss);

    for(std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " - " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it prints 1 for every word, even if it appears twice. What could be the problem? I'm not sure if my test for an iterator not to be empty is correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888879/elegant-ways-to-count-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-file

Comment: You can also see the other solutions here : [Elegant ways to count the frequency of words in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888879/elegant-ways-to-count-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `map` automatically constructs an item with the default constructor, when you access a key that doesn't exist yet, you can simply say:

```
while (iss >> words) {
    ++m[words];
}
```

The default value of new items will be 0 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667355/mapint-int-default-values)).

Your previous map logic was fine except that you had the condition reversed; it should have been `if (it == m.end())` instead of `!=`, since `find()` returns `end()` when the element is *not* found. As GWW points out in his answer, `insert` has no effect when the item is already in the map, which is the only time you were using it.

Also, your loop was not handling input properly; you need to check if the state of the stream is invalid *after* reading in the value, but *before* using it (since the value is garbage if the stream was at its end). The idiomatic way to handle input is with the `while (is >> value)` construct; if you want to do it yourself then this is equivalent:

```
while (true) {
   iss >> words;
   if (!iss) {
       break;
   }

   // Process words...
}
```

Finally, it's a little misleading to name your variable "words" when it will only contain one word at a time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I will quote from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/).

> Because map containers do not allow
>   for duplicate key values, the
>   insertion operation checks for each
>   element inserted whether another
>   element exists already in the
>   container with the same key value, if
>   so, the element is not inserted and
>   its mapped value is not changed in any
>   way.

In your code you are trying to insert on top of an element already in the map.  You should change

```
m.insert(it, std::pair<std::string, int>(words, m[words] + 1));
```

to

```
it->second+=1;
```